# is it possible to do fuzzy match merge with python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames which I want to merge based on a column. However, due to alternate spellings, different number of spaces, absence/presence of diacritical marks, I would like to be able to merge as long as they are similar to one another.

Any similarity algorithm will do (soundex, Levenshtein, difflib's).

Say one DataFrame has the following data:

```
df1 = DataFrame([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]], index=['one','two','three','four','five'], columns=['number'])

       number
one         1
two         2
three       3
four        4
five        5

df2 = DataFrame([['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],['e']], index=['one','too','three','fours','five'], columns=['letter'])

      letter
one        a
too        b
three      c
fours      d
five       e
```

Then I want to get the resulting DataFrame

```
       number letter
one         1      a
two         2      b
three       3      c
four        4      d
five        5      e
```

Comment: Yes with [d6tjoin](https://github.com/d6t/d6tjoin) see [MergeTop1 notebook](https://github.com/d6t/d6tjoin/blob/master/examples-top1.ipynb)

Comment: The accepted solution fails in the cases where no close matches are found. For a simple way around, [see this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908516/9698684)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Similar to @locojay suggestion, you can apply [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)'s [`get_close_matches`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) to `df2`'s index and then apply a [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#joining-on-index):

```
In [23]: import difflib 

In [24]: difflib.get_close_matches
Out[24]: <function difflib.get_close_matches>

In [25]: df2.index = df2.index.map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1.index)[0])

In [26]: df2
Out[26]: 
      letter
one        a
two        b
three      c
four       d
five       e

In [31]: df1.join(df2)
Out[31]: 
       number letter
one         1      a
two         2      b
three       3      c
four        4      d
five        5      e
```

.

If these were columns, in the same vein you could apply to the column then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
df1 = DataFrame([[1,'one'],[2,'two'],[3,'three'],[4,'four'],[5,'five']], columns=['number', 'name'])
df2 = DataFrame([['a','one'],['b','too'],['c','three'],['d','fours'],['e','five']], columns=['letter', 'name'])

df2['name'] = df2['name'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['name'])[0])
df1.merge(df2)
```

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to do this between rows of one column? I'm trying to find duplicates that might have typos

Comment: you can use n=1 to limit the results to 1. https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches

Comment: How to go about it if the two dataframes have different lengths?

Comment: This solution fails in many places and I prefer https://github.com/d6t/d6tjoin. You can customize similarity function, affinegap is a better similarity metric, it's multi-core for faster compute, deals with duplicates matches etc

Comment: This solution fails in the cases where no close matches where found. [Here's a simple way around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908516/9698684)

Comment: For those that say it fails, I think that is more of an issue of how to implement this into your pipeline, and not a fault of the solution, which is simple and elegant.

Comment: I used a similar solution but used `[:1]` to resize the result list from `get_close_matches` and make sure it doesn't throw a `KeyError`

Comment: Is it possible to return matches _with the similiarity score included_ with difflib?

Answer (score 75):

## Using `fuzzywuzzy`

Since there are no examples with the `fuzzywuzzy` package, here's a function I wrote which will return all matches based on a threshold you can set as a user:

---

**Example datframe**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Strawberry']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['Aple', 'Mango', 'Orag', 'Straw', 'Bannanna', 'Berry']})

# df1
          Key
0       Apple
1      Banana
2      Orange
3  Strawberry

# df2
        Key
0      Aple
1     Mango
2      Orag
3     Straw
4  Bannanna
5     Berry
```

**Function for fuzzy matching**

```
def fuzzy_merge(df_1, df_2, key1, key2, threshold=90, limit=2):
    """
    :param df_1: the left table to join
    :param df_2: the right table to join
    :param key1: key column of the left table
    :param key2: key column of the right table
    :param threshold: how close the matches should be to return a match, based on Levenshtein distance
    :param limit: the amount of matches that will get returned, these are sorted high to low
    :return: dataframe with boths keys and matches
    """
    s = df_2[key2].tolist()
    
    m = df_1[key1].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, s, limit=limit))    
    df_1['matches'] = m
    
    m2 = df_1['matches'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([i[0] for i in x if i[1] >= threshold]))
    df_1['matches'] = m2
    
    return df_1
```

**Using our function on the dataframes:** *#1*

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

fuzzy_merge(df1, df2, 'Key', 'Key', threshold=80)

          Key       matches
0       Apple          Aple
1      Banana      Bannanna
2      Orange          Orag
3  Strawberry  Straw, Berry
```

**Using our function on the dataframes:** *#2*

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['Microsoft', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'IBM']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col2':['Mcrsoft', 'gogle', 'Amason', 'BIM']})

fuzzy_merge(df1, df2, 'Col1', 'Col2', 80)

        Col1  matches
0  Microsoft  Mcrsoft
1     Google    gogle
2     Amazon   Amason
3        IBM
```

## Installation:

**Pip**

```
pip install fuzzywuzzy
```

**Anaconda**

```
conda install -c conda-forge fuzzywuzzy
```

Comment: is there a way to carry all of df2's columns over to the match? lets say c is a primary or foreign key youd like to keep of table 2 (df2)

Comment: @Tinkinc did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: hey Erfan, when you get a mo think you could update this to be used with pandas 1.0? i wonder what sort of performance boost it would get if you changed the engine in apply to Cython or Numba

Comment: This solutions looks really promising for my problem as well. But could you explain as to how this will work when I do not have a common column in both the datasets? How can I create a match column in one of the two datasets that gives me the score? I have used your #2 solution. I am not sure why it is taking so much time to run.

Comment: I have read the comments. I will soon update the code which helps the problem of @Tinkinc and try to implement apply with Cython or Numba to speed up code runtime @ Datanvoice.

Comment: Sorry, I get `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` when I merge using your function, any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: If you need the matched keys too, you can use `s = df_2.to_dict()[key2]`

Comment: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/issues/165 describes @suricactus's dict strategy a little more. From there you can merge on the index to get the rest of df2's columns.

Comment: this works well, any way to get this working @Erfan to the whole sheet? so key + the rest of the data.

Comment: @iHaag a bit late to the game but I have added the functionality you are looking for in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66833195/5125264

Comment: I have asked a new question about @Tinkinc ' comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72348033/fuzzy-merge-with-python-pandas

Answer (score 24):

I have written a Python package which aims to solve this problem:

`pip install fuzzymatcher`

You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/RobinL/fuzzymatcher) and docs [here](https://github.com/RobinL/fuzzymatcher/blob/master/examples.ipynb).

Basic usage:

Given two dataframes `df_left` and `df_right`, which you want to fuzzy join, you can write the following:

```
from fuzzymatcher import link_table, fuzzy_left_join

# Columns to match on from df_left
left_on = ["fname", "mname", "lname",  "dob"]

# Columns to match on from df_right
right_on = ["name", "middlename", "surname", "date"]

# The link table potentially contains several matches for each record
fuzzymatcher.link_table(df_left, df_right, left_on, right_on)
```

Or if you just want to link on the closest match:

```
fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(df_left, df_right, left_on, right_on)
```

Comment: Would've been awesome if it didn't had as many dependencies honestly, first I had to install visual studio build tool, now I get the error: `no such module: fts4`

Comment: `name 'fuzzymatcher' is not defined`

Comment: @RobinL can you pleas elaborate to how fix the: `no such module: fts4` issue? I have been trying to work this with zero success.

Comment: @TaL, have you resolved it?

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker - I think I used the answer from below of reddy. but it took me a lot of sweat to solve this issue

Comment: @TaL, I resolved last night! Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I would use Jaro-Winkler, because it is one of the most performant and accurate approximate string matching algorithms currently available [[Cohen, et al.](http://dc-pubs.dbs.uni-leipzig.de/files/Cohen2003Acomparisonofstringdistance.pdf)], [[Winkler](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.46.7347)].

This is how I would do it with Jaro-Winkler from the [jellyfish](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jellyfish) package:

```
def get_closest_match(x, list_strings):

  best_match = None
  highest_jw = 0

  for current_string in list_strings:
    current_score = jellyfish.jaro_winkler(x, current_string)

    if(current_score > highest_jw):
      highest_jw = current_score
      best_match = current_string

  return best_match

df1 = pandas.DataFrame([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]], index=['one','two','three','four','five'], columns=['number'])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame([['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],['e']], index=['one','too','three','fours','five'], columns=['letter'])

df2.index = df2.index.map(lambda x: get_closest_match(x, df1.index))

df1.join(df2)
```

Output:

```
    number  letter
one     1   a
two     2   b
three   3   c
four    4   d
five    5   e
```

Comment: how about

    def get_closest_match(x, list_strings):
        return sorted(list_strings, key=lambda y: jellyfish.jaro_winkler(x, y), reverse=True)[0]

Comment: There any way to speed this up? This code doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 11):

### For a general approach: `fuzzy_merge`

For a more general scenario in which we want to merge columns from two dataframes which contain slightly different strings, the following function uses [`difflib.get_close_matches`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) along with [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) in order to mimic the functionality of pandas' `merge` but with fuzzy matching:

```
import difflib 

def fuzzy_merge(df1, df2, left_on, right_on, how='inner', cutoff=0.6):
    df_other= df2.copy()
    df_other[left_on] = [get_closest_match(x, df1[left_on], cutoff) 
                         for x in df_other[right_on]]
    return df1.merge(df_other, on=left_on, how=how)

def get_closest_match(x, other, cutoff):
    matches = difflib.get_close_matches(x, other, cutoff=cutoff)
    return matches[0] if matches else None
```

---

Here are some use cases with two sample dataframes:

```
print(df1)

     key   number
0    one       1
1    two       2
2  three       3
3   four       4
4   five       5

print(df2)

                 key_close  letter
0                    three      c
1                      one      a
2                      too      b
3                    fours      d
4  a very different string      e
```

With the above example, we'd get:

```
fuzzy_merge(df1, df2, left_on='key', right_on='key_close')

     key  number key_close letter
0    one       1       one      a
1    two       2       too      b
2  three       3     three      c
3   four       4     fours      d
```

And we could do a left join with:

```
fuzzy_merge(df1, df2, left_on='key', right_on='key_close', how='left')

     key  number key_close letter
0    one       1       one      a
1    two       2       too      b
2  three       3     three      c
3   four       4     fours      d
4   five       5       NaN    NaN
```

For a right join, we'd have all non-matching keys in the left dataframe to `None`:

```
fuzzy_merge(df1, df2, left_on='key', right_on='key_close', how='right')

     key  number                key_close letter
0    one     1.0                      one      a
1    two     2.0                      too      b
2  three     3.0                    three      c
3   four     4.0                    fours      d
4   None     NaN  a very different string      e
```

---

Also note that [`difflib.get_close_matches`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) **will return an empty list** if no item is matched within the cutoff. In the shared example, if we change the last index in `df2` to say:

```
print(df2)

                          letter
one                          a
too                          b
three                        c
fours                        d
a very different string      e
```

We'd get an `index out of range` error:

```
df2.index.map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1.index)[0])
```

> IndexError: list index out of range

In order to solve this the above function `get_closest_match` will return the closest match by indexing the list returned by `difflib.get_close_matches` *only if* it actually contains any matches.

Comment: I'd suggest using `apply` to make it faster: `df_other[left_on] = df_other[right_on].apply(lambda x: get_closest_match(x, df1[left_on], cutoff))`

Comment: apply isn't faster than list comps @irene :) check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758

Comment: Hmm...I just tried the same code, it was visibly faster for the data that I had. Maybe it's data-dependent?

Comment: Normally for reliable timings you need benchmarking on large sample sizes. But on my experience, list-comps are usually as fast or faster @irene Also do note that apply is basically just looping over the rows too

Comment: Got it, will try list comprehensions next time `apply` is to slow for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html does not have a hook function to do this on the fly. Would be nice though...

I would just do a separate step and use difflib getclosest_matches to create a new column in  one of the 2 dataframes and the merge/join on the fuzzy matched column

Comment: Could you explain how to use `difflib.get_closest_matches` to create such a column and then merge on that?

Answer (score 5):

I used Fuzzymatcher package and this worked well for me. Visit this [link](https://github.com/RobinL/fuzzymatcher) for more details on this.

use the below command to install

```
pip install fuzzymatcher
```

Below is the sample Code (already submitted by RobinL above)

```
from fuzzymatcher import link_table, fuzzy_left_join

# Columns to match on from df_left
left_on = ["fname", "mname", "lname",  "dob"]

# Columns to match on from df_right
right_on = ["name", "middlename", "surname", "date"]

# The link table potentially contains several matches for each record
fuzzymatcher.link_table(df_left, df_right, left_on, right_on)
```

**Errors you may get**

1. ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero---> Refer to this
   [link](https://github.com/RobinL/fuzzymatcher/issues/42) to resolve it
2. OperationalError: No Such Module:fts4 --> downlaod the sqlite3.dll
   from [here](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and replace the DLL file in your python or anaconda
   DLLs folder.

Pros :

1. **Works faster.** *In my case, I compared one dataframe with 3000 rows with anohter dataframe with 170,000 records* . This also uses SQLite3 search across text. So faster than many
2. **Can check across multiple columns and 2 dataframes**. *In my case, I was looking for closest match based on address and company name. Sometimes, company name might be same but address is the good thing to check too.*
3. Gives you score for all the closest matches for the same record. you choose whats the cutoff score.

cons:

1. Original package installation is buggy
2. Required C++ and visual studios installed too
3. Wont work for 64 bit anaconda/Python

Comment: Thanks reddy... currently running this on a dataset with 6000 rows matched up against a dataset with 3 million rows, and praying... Do you think this will run faster than fuzzywuzzy?

Comment: Hi @Parseltongue: This data is huge in your case. I dont think any fuzzywuzzy seems to be efficient against more than a million, But you can definitely give it a try for this one. I ran 6000 rows against 0.8 million rows and was pretty good.

Comment: How to install the sqlite model? Tried all possible options - still does not work :(

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker sqlite module is builtin python so you don't need to install!

Comment: @reddy I havent been able to figure out the zero float division error. I am getting it in after installing in colab with pip, could you please help me out?

Answer (score 5):

There is a package called `fuzzy_pandas` that can use `levenshtein`, `jaro`, `metaphone` and `bilenco` methods. With some great examples [here](https://github.com/jsoma/fuzzy_pandas/blob/master/examples/fuzzy_pandas%20examples.ipynb)

```
import pandas as pd
import fuzzy_pandas as fpd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Strawberry']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['Aple', 'Mango', 'Orag', 'Straw', 'Bannanna', 'Berry']})

results = fpd.fuzzy_merge(df1, df2,
            left_on='Key',
            right_on='Key',
            method='levenshtein',
            threshold=0.6)

results.head()
```

```
  Key    Key
0 Apple  Aple
1 Banana Bannanna
2 Orange Orag
```

Answer (score 4):

## Using `thefuzz`

Using SeatGeek's great package `thefuzz`, which makes use of Levenshtein distance. This works with data held in columns. It adds matches as rows rather than columns, to preserve a tidy dataset, and allows additional columns to be easily pulled through to the output dataframe.

---

**Sample data**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':['one','two','three','four','five'], 'col_b':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

    col_a   col_b
0   one     1
1   two     2
2   three   3
3   four    4
4   five    5

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':['one','too','three','fours','five'], 'col_b':['a','b','c','d','e']})

    col_a   col_b
0   one     a
1   too     b
2   three   c
3   fours   d
4   five    e
```

**Function used to do the matching**

```
def fuzzy_match(
    df_left, df_right, column_left, column_right, threshold=90, limit=1
):
    # Create a series
    series_matches = df_left[column_left].apply(
        lambda x: process.extract(x, df_right[column_right], limit=limit)            # Creates a series with id from df_left and column name _column_left_, with _limit_ matches per item
    )

    # Convert matches to a tidy dataframe
    df_matches = series_matches.to_frame()
    df_matches = df_matches.explode(column_left)     # Convert list of matches to rows
    df_matches[
        ['match_string', 'match_score', 'df_right_id']
    ] = pd.DataFrame(df_matches[column_left].tolist(), index=df_matches.index)       # Convert match tuple to columns
    df_matches.drop(column_left, axis=1, inplace=True)      # Drop column of match tuples

    # Reset index, as in creating a tidy dataframe we've introduced multiple rows per id, so that no longer functions well as the index
    if df_matches.index.name:
        index_name = df_matches.index.name     # Stash index name
    else:
        index_name = 'index'        # Default used by pandas
    df_matches.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df_matches.rename(columns={index_name: 'df_left_id'}, inplace=True)       # The previous index has now become a column: rename for ease of reference

    # Drop matches below threshold
    df_matches.drop(
        df_matches.loc[df_matches['match_score'] < threshold].index,
        inplace=True
    )

    return df_matches
```

**Use function and merge data**

```
import pandas as pd
from thefuzz import process

df_matches = fuzzy_match(
    df1,
    df2,
    'col_a',
    'col_a',
    threshold=60,
    limit=1
)

df_output = df1.merge(
    df_matches,
    how='left',
    left_index=True,
    right_on='df_left_id'
).merge(
    df2,
    how='left',
    left_on='df_right_id',
    right_index=True,
    suffixes=['_df1', '_df2']
)

df_output.set_index('df_left_id', inplace=True)       # For some reason the first merge operation wrecks the dataframe's index. Recreated from the value we have in the matches lookup table

df_output = df_output[['col_a_df1', 'col_b_df1', 'col_b_df2']]      # Drop columns used in the matching
df_output.index.name = 'id'

id  col_a_df1   col_b_df1   col_b_df2
0   one         1           a
1   two         2           b
2   three       3           c
3   four        4           d
4   five        5           e
```

Answer (score 2):

As a heads up, this basically works, except if no match is found, or if you have NaNs in either column. Instead of directly applying `get_close_matches`, I found it easier to apply the following function. The choice of NaN replacements will depend a lot on your dataset.

```
def fuzzy_match(a, b):
    left = '1' if pd.isnull(a) else a
    right = b.fillna('2')
    out = difflib.get_close_matches(left, right)
    return out[0] if out else np.NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [d6tjoin](https://github.com/d6t/d6tjoin) for that

```
import d6tjoin.top1
d6tjoin.top1.MergeTop1(df1.reset_index(),df2.reset_index(),
       fuzzy_left_on=['index'],fuzzy_right_on=['index']).merge()['merged']
```

`index  number index_right letter
0    one       1         one      a
1    two       2         too      b
2  three       3       three      c
3   four       4       fours      d
4   five       5        five      e`

It has a variety of additional features such as:

- check join quality, pre and post join
- customize similarity function, eg edit distance vs hamming distance
- specify max distance
- multi-core compute

For details see

- [MergeTop1 examples](https://github.com/d6t/d6tjoin/blob/master/examples-top1.ipynb) - Best match join examples notebook
- [PreJoin examples](https://github.com/d6t/d6tjoin/blob/master/examples-prejoin.ipynb) - Examples for diagnosing join problems

Comment: Just tested this, it gives me weird results back, for example it matched `government` with `business`, is there a way to configure the threshold for the matching score?

Comment: Yes see [reference docs](https://d6tjoin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/d6tjoin.html#module-d6tjoin.top1) you can pass `top_limit` and might also want to change `fun_diff` to `fun_diff=[affinegap.affineGapDistance]` which tends to give better matches.

Answer (score 2):

I have used `fuzzywuzz` in a very minimal way whilst matching the existing behaviour and keywords of `merge` in `pandas`.

Just specify your accepted `threshold` for matching (between `0` and `100`):

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def fuzzy_merge(df, df2, on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None, how='inner', threshold=80):
    
    def fuzzy_apply(x, df, column, threshold=threshold):
        if type(x)!=str:
            return None
        
        match, score, *_ = process.extract(x, df[column], limit=1)[0]
            
        if score >= threshold:
            return match

        else:
            return None
    
    if on is not None:
        left_on = on
        right_on = on

    # create temp column as the best fuzzy match (or None!)
    df2['tmp'] = df2[right_on].apply(
        fuzzy_apply, 
        df=df, 
        column=left_on, 
        threshold=threshold
    )

    merged_df = df.merge(df2, how=how, left_on=left_on, right_on='tmp')
    
    del merged_df['tmp']
    
    return merged_df
```

Try it out using the example data:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Strawberry']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['Aple', 'Mango', 'Orag', 'Straw', 'Bannanna', 'Berry']})

fuzzy_merge(df, df2, on='Key', threshold=80)
```

Comment: Instead of process.extract with a limit of 1, you can directly use process.extractOne, which only extracts the best match.

Answer (score 0):

For more complex use cases to match rows with many columns you can use `recordlinkage` package. `recordlinkage` provides all the tools to fuzzy match rows between `pandas` data frames which helps to deduplicate your data when merging. I have written a detailed article about the package [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-perform-fuzzy-dataframe-row-matching-with-recordlinkage-b53ca0cb944c?source=your_stories_page-------------------------------------)

Answer (score 0):

if the join axis is numeric this could also be used to match indexes with a specified tolerance:

```
def fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, tol=None):
    index1 = df1.index.values
    index2 = df2.index.values

    diff = np.abs(index1.reshape((-1, 1)) - index2)
    mask_j = np.argmin(diff, axis=1)  # min. of each column
    mask_i = np.arange(mask_j.shape[0])

    df1_ = df1.iloc[mask_i]
    df2_ = df2.iloc[mask_j]

    if tol is not None:
        mask = np.abs(df2_.index.values - df1_.index.values) <= tol
        df1_ = df1_.loc[mask]
        df2_ = df2_.loc[mask]

    df2_.index = df1_.index

    out = pd.concat([df1_, df2_], axis=1)
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

**TheFuzz** is the new version of a **fuzzywuzzy**

In order to fuzzy-join string-elements in two big tables you can do this:

1. Use apply to go row by row
2. Use swifter to parallel, speed up and visualize default apply function (with colored progress bar)
3. Use OrderedDict from collections to get rid of duplicates in the output of merge and keep the initial order
4. Increase ***limit*** in `thefuzz.process.extract` to see more options for merge (stored in a list of tuples with % of similarity)

'*' You can use `thefuzz.process.extractOne` instead of `thefuzz.process.extract` to return just one best-matched item (without specifying any ***limit***). However, be aware that several results could have same % of similarity and you will get only one of them.

'**' Somehow the swifter takes a minute or two before starting the actual apply. If you need to process small tables you can skip this step and just use *progress_apply* instead

> ```
> from thefuzz import process
> from collections import OrderedDict
> import swifter    
>
>
> def match(x):
>     matches = process.extract(x, df1, limit=6)
>     matches = list(OrderedDict((x, True) for x in matches).keys())
>     print(f'{x:20} : {matches}')
>
>     return str(matches)
>
>
> df1 = df['name'].values
> df2['matches'] = df2['name'].swifter.apply(lambda x: match(x))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this very efficient. The details in the description of the function:

```
from fuzzywuzzy.process import extract

def efficient_matching(df1,
                       col1,
                       df2,
                       col2,
                       limit=3,
                       length_diff=3,
                       first_letter_match=2
                       ):
    """
    For each name that we want to find matches for, it's more efficient to only look at a subset of potential matches. 
    One way to narrow down all the matches to potential matches is length. Here are 2 methods:
    1. If the name is "Markos", we don't need to check how similar markos is to names with length less than 4 or 
    more than 8. This window is determined by length_diff.
    2. We consider names from the corpus whose first 2 letters are similar the first letters of the name we want to find
    the match for.

    limit: Gives how many closest matches to return.
    """
    df1[col1] = df1[col1].astype(str)
    df2[col2] = df2[col2].astype(str)

    df1['_len_'] = df1[col1].apply(len)
    df2['_len_'] = df2[col2].apply(len)
    df2 = df2[df2['_len_'] >= 2]

    matches = df1[[col1, '_len_']].apply(lambda x: 
                                        extract(x[0], 
                                                df2[
                                                    ((df2['_len_'] - x[1]).abs() < length_diff) &
                                                    (df2[col2].str[:first_letter_match]==x[0][:first_letter_match])
                                                    ][col2].tolist(), 
                                                limit = limit
                                                ), 
                                        axis=1
                                        ) 
    return matches
```