# How to Normalize Names

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, normalize

I am using pandas dataframes and I have data where I have customers per company. However, the company titles vary slightly but ultimately affect the data.
Example:

```
Company    Customers
AAAB       1,000
AAAB Inc.  900
The AAAB Inc.  20
AAAB the INC   10
```

I want to get the total customers out of a data base of several different companies with the companies having non-standard names. Any idea where I should start?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13636848/1240268, I think best place to start is have the actual list of companies and try and work out a good metric/function for similar names.

Comment: I checked out that link and saw a great use to the get_close_matches. However, I had some trouble finding a proper execution. I used                                            #Spend['Manufacturer'] = Spend['Manufacturer'].map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x,Spend['SKU/Catalog #'],5))
I also tried the below 
def spendd(n):
    manuf = []
    for i in n:
        Spend['Manufacturer'].map(lambda i: difflib.get_close_matches(i,Spend['Manufacturer'],5))
    return manuf

spendd('Manufacturer') 

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

I am trying to fix this error but am unsure how.

Comment: trigram similarity works wonders. I usually use a tool like cleanco and then use trigram similarity in PostgreSQL or a similarity match in Snowflake [both will work potentially faster than Python in many cases due to the cost of retrieving and storing the data, especially Snowflake]

Answer (score 10):

I remember reading [this blog](http://seatgeek.com/blog/dev/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python) about the [fuzzywuzzy library](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) (looking into [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13636848/1240268)), which can do this:

```
pip install fuzzywuzzy
```

You can use its partial_ratio function to "fuzzy match" the strings:

```
In [11]: from fuzzywuzzy.fuzz import partial_ratio

In [12]: partial_ratio('AAAB', 'the AAAB inc.')
Out[12]: 100
```

Which seems confident about it being a good match!

```
In [13]: partial_ratio('AAAB', 'AAPL')
Out[13]: 50

In [14]: partial_ratio('AAAB', 'Google')
Out[14]: 0
```

We can take the best match in the actual company list (assuming you have it):

```
In [15]: co_list = ['AAAB', 'AAPL', 'GOOG']

In [16]: df.Company.apply(lambda mistyped_co: max(co_list, 
                                                  key=lambda co: partial_ratio(mistyped_co, co)))
Out[16]: 
0    AAAB
1    AAAB
2    AAAB
3    AAAB
Name: Company, dtype: object
```

*I strongly suspect there is something in scikit learn or a numpy library to do this more efficiently on large datasets... but this should get the job done.*

If you don't have the company list you'll probably have to do something more clevererer...

Comment: Hey this is awesome. Thanks for exposing me to the fuzzywuzzy article. I will take some time to check it out and see how I can apply it.

Answer (score 1):

```
splitCompaniesSet = map( lambda cmpnyName : 
    set( map( lambda name : name.split(" "), cmpnyName ) ), dataFrame['Company'] )
```

I think that's right.

Basically create a list of sets, each set has the company name split. Then, starting with the first element, find the [set intersection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) of every other element with that one. For every non-empty intersection, change the name to whatever the simplest match was
among all the non-empty resulting sets, i.e. take one more set intersection with all the nonempty sets and set the result to be the company name for all those non-empty matches.

Then go on to the next `Company` that resulted in an empty set when intersected with the first company name. Then do this for the next `Company` that was empty for the first two you tried, and so on.

There's probably a more efficient way to do it, though.

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a go. I have been looking up normalization on the unicodedata module. I was not sure if that would apply to this situation however. I also discovered from zope.component import getUtility
from plone.i18n.normalizer.interfaces import IIDNormalizer 
 from http://developer.plone.org/misc/normalizing_ids.html  and am not sure how I could import those modules as well. It seemed I needed to download something else.

Comment: Ok, I see. Instead of messing with sets, it looks like you could use `fuzzywuzzy.fuzz.partial_ratio` and set all the ones where `partial_ratio`=100 to be the same name.  This would remove the need to have the company list as Andy suggested.