# Searching one Python dataframe / dictionary for fuzzy matches in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I have the following pandas dataframe with 50,000 unique rows and 20 columns (included is a snippet of the relevant columns):

**df1**:

```
            PRODUCT_ID           PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
0           165985858958         "Fish Burger with Lettuce"
1           185965653252         "Chicken Salad with Dressing"
2           165958565556         "Pork and Honey Rissoles"
3           655262522233         "Cheese, Ham and Tomato Sandwich"
4           857485966653         "Coleslaw with Yoghurt Dressing"
5           524156285551         "Lemon and Raspberry Cheesecake"
```

I also have the following dataframe (which I also have saved in dictionary form) which has 2 columns and 20,000 unique rows:

**df2 (also saved as dict_2)**

```
       PROD_ID   PROD_DESCRIPTION
0      548576    "Fish Burger"
1      156956    "Chckn Salad w/Ranch Dressing"
2      257848    "Rissoles - Lamb & Rosemary"
3      298770    "Lemn C-cake"
4      651452    "Potato Salad with Bacon"
5      100256    "Cheese Cake - Lemon Raspberry Coulis"
```

What I am wanting to do is compare the "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION" field in df1 to the the "PROD_DESCRIPTION" field in df2 and find the closest match/matches to help with the heavy lifting part.  I would then need to manually check the matches but it would be a lot quicker  The ideal outcome would look like this, e.g. with one or more part matches noted:

```
     PRODUCT_ID      PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION               PROD_ID   PROD_DESCRIPTION
0    165985858958    "Fish Burger with Lettuce"        548576    "Fish Burger"
1    185965653252    "Chicken Salad with Dressing"     156956    "Chckn Salad w/Ranch Dressing"
2    165958565556    "Pork and Honey Rissoles"         257848    "Rissoles - Lamb & Rosemary"     
3    655262522233    "Cheese, Ham and Tomato Sandwich" NaN       NaN
4    857485966653    "Coleslaw with Yoghurt Dressing"  NaN       NaN
5    524156285551    "Lemon and Raspberry Cheesecake"  298770    "Lemn C-cake"
6    524156285551    "Lemon and Raspberry Cheesecake"  100256    "Cheese Cake - Lemon Raspberry Coulis"
```

I have already completed a join which has identified the exact matches. It's not important that the index is retained as the Product ID's in each df are unique.  The results can also be saved into a new dataframe as this will then be applied to a third dataframe that has around 14 million rows.

I've used the following questions and answers (amongst others):

[Is it possible to do fuzzy match merge with python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas)
[Fuzzy merge match with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964546/python-pandas-fuzzy-merge-match-with-duplicates?rq=1) including trying jellyfish module as suggested in one of the answers
[Python fuzzy matching fuzzywuzzy keep only the best match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055817/python-fuzzy-matching-fuzzywuzzy-keep-only-best-match)
[Fuzzy match items in a column of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977401/how-do-i-fuzzy-match-items-in-a-column-of-an-array-in-python)

and also various loops/functions/mapping etc. but have had no success, either getting the first "fuzzy match" which has a low score or no matches being detected.

I like the idea of a matching/distance score column being generated as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259464/how-to-apply-a-fuzzy-matching-function-on-the-target-and-reference-columns-for-p) as it would then allow me to speed up the manual checking process.

I'm using Python 2.7, pandas and have fuzzywuzzy installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using `fuzz.ratio` as my distance metric, calculate my distance matrix like this

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=df2.index)

for i in df3.index:
    for j in df3.columns:
        vi = df.get_value(i, 'PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION')
        vj = df2.get_value(j, 'PROD_DESCRIPTION')
        df3.set_value(
            i, j, fuzz.ratio(vi, vj))

print(df3)

    0   1   2   3   4   5
0  63  15  24  23  34  27
1  26  84  19  21  52  32
2  18  31  33  12  35  34
3  10  31  35  10  41  42
4  29  52  32  10  42  12
5  15  28  21  49   8  55
```

Set a threshold for acceptable distance.  I set `50`
Find the index value (for `df2`) that has maximum value for every row.

```
threshold = df3.max(1) > 50
idxmax = df3.idxmax(1)
```

Make assignments

```
df['PROD_ID'] = np.where(threshold, df2.loc[idxmax, 'PROD_ID'].values, np.nan)
df['PROD_DESCRIPTION'] = np.where(threshold, df2.loc[idxmax, 'PROD_DESCRIPTION'].values, np.nan)
df
```

[image]

Comment: I've used this on a small subset of the data and it looks like it's working well.  I've just set it to run on the larger block with four different iterations to test the various fuzz usages (i.e. fuzz.ratio, fuzz.partial_ratio etc.) so I can see which gives the best results.  Appreciate your help with the heavy lifting on my thesis.

Comment: Just to add - fuzz.token_sort_ratio produced the most accurate outcome with around 70% successful matches.

Comment: @gincard how much data and how fast was it... aproximately

Comment: I broke it down into the 30 categories.  One that was 6300 x 4500 took approximately 15 mins.  2000 x 2000 took seconds.  The largest (23000 x 10000) took about 4.5 hrs.  That one was messy and had less well-defined matches.  Computer has 32GB DDR3 RAM & an overclocked i5 processor.

Comment: That's not horrible.  I was fearful of worse

Comment: I just upgraded my RAM from 8GB.  I stopped the 23000 x 10000 one after 10 hours and it was about 80% of the way through the fuzz.ratio calculations!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to iterate over both dataframes and populate either a dict of a 3rd dataframe with your desired information:

```
d = {
    'df1_id': [],
    'df1_prod_desc': [],
    'df2_id': [],
    'df2_prod_desc': [],
    'fuzzywuzzy_sim': []
}
for _, df1_row in df1.iterrows():
    for _, df2_row in df2.iterrows():
        d['df1_id'] = df1_row['PRODUCT_ID']
        ...
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to be able to comment on answer from **@piRSquared**. Hence this answer.

- The definition of '**vi**' and '**vj**' didn't go through with an error (`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_value'`). It worked when I inserted an "underscore". E.g. `vi = df._get_value(i, 'PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION')`
- Similar issue persisted for '`set_value`' and the same solution worked there too. E.g. `df3._set_value(i, j, fuzz.ratio(vi, vj))`
- Generating `idxmax` posed another error (`TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype`) which was because contents of df3 (the fuzzy ratios) were of type 'object'. I converted all of them to numeric just before defining `threshold` and it worked. E.g. `df3 = df3.apply(pd.to_numeric)`

A million thanks to **@piRSquared** for the solution. For a Python novice like me, it worked like a charm. I am posting this answer to make it easy for other newbies like me.