# Merging based on few column conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames which I am trying to merge based on matching values of few columns - Amount, Name, Year, Month.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on=['Name1','Year1','Month1','Amount1'], 
                        right_on=['Name2','Year2','Month2','Amount2'])
```

I want to incorporate the condition such that a variance of 6 months and a variance of 1000$ is allowed This means - Besides, the exact matching, matching should even occur if there is a difference of at most 6 months between Month1 and Month2. Similarly, matching should also occur if the amount differ by at most 1000$. Year and Name should always have exact matches.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas)

Comment: @ako I have to basically do it on numbers. Month is a number between 1 to 12, and then Amount is certain number. The post suggested by you is used for matching strings.