# What's a better way to clean data before a merge?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, merge

I have two different data frames that I need to merge and the merge column ('title') needs to be cleaned up before the merge can happen. Sample data example looks like the following;

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a12bcde0','b20bcde9'], 'title': ['a.b. company','company_b']})

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'serial_number': ['01a2b345','10ab2030','40ab4060'],'title':['ab company','company_b (123)','company_f']})
```

As expected the merge will not succeed on the first title. I have been using the `replace()` method but it get's unmanageable very quickly because I have 100s of titles to correct due to spellings, case sensitivity, etc.

Any other suggestions regarding how to best cleanup and merge the data?

Full Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a12bcde0','b20bcde9'], 'title': ['a.b. company','company_b']})

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'serial_number': ['01a2b345','10ab2030','40ab4060'],'title':['ab company','company_b (123)','company_f']}) 

data2['title'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r"\s\(.*\)",value=r'')

replacements = {
   'title': {
        r'a.b. company *.*': 'ab company'
    }
}
data1.replace(replacements, regex=True, inplace=True)

pd.merge(data1, data2, on='title')
```

Comment: I can't think of a better way than this ... what are you imagining?

Comment: You could use the [`fuzzywuzzy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy) package, and use the function `ratio` for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, there is no perfect solution for this problem, but I suggest doing two things:

- Do any easy cleaning you can do before hand, including removing any characters you don't expect.
- Apply some fuzzy matching logic

You'll see this isn't perfect since even this example doesn't work 100% percent.

---

First, let's start by making your example a tiny bit more complicated, introducing a regular typo (`coampany_b` instead of `company_b`, something that won't get picked up by the easy cleaning below)

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a12bcde0','b20bcde9', 'csdfsjkbku'], 'title': ['a.b. company','company_b', 'coampany_b']})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'serial_number': ['01a2b345','10ab2030','40ab4060'],'title':['ab company','company_b (123)','company_f']})
```

---

Then let's assume you only expect [a-z] characters as @Maarten Fabré mentioned. So let's lowercase everything and remove anything else.

```
data1['cleaned_title'] = data1['title'].str.lower().replace(regex=True,inplace=False,to_replace=r"[^a-z]", value=r'')
data2['cleaned_title'] = data2['title'].str.lower().replace(regex=True,inplace=False,to_replace=r"[^a-z]", value=r'')
```

---

Now, let's use [difflib's get_close_matches](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) (read more and other options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas))

```
import difflib
data1['closestmatch'] = data1.cleaned_title.apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, data2.cleaned_title)[0])
data2['closestmatch'] = data1.cleaned_title.apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, data2.cleaned_title)[0])
```

Here is the resulting data1, looking good!

```
    id          title           cleaned_title   closestmatch
0   a12bcde0    a.b. company    abcompany       abcompany
1   b20bcde9    company_b       companyb        companyb
2   csdfsjkbku  coampany_b      coampanyb       companyb
```

Now, here is data2, looking a bit *less good*... We asked it to find the closest match, so it found one for company_f, while you clearly don't want it.

```
    serial_number   title           cleaned_title   closestmatch
0   01a2b345        ab company      abcompany       abcompany
1   10ab2030        company_b (123) companyb        companyb
2   40ab4060        company_f       companyf        companyb
```

**The ideal case scenario is if you have a clean list of company titles on the side, in which case you should find the closest match based on that**. If you don't, you'll have to get creative or manually clean up the hit and miss.

To wrap this up, you can now perform a regular merge on 'closestmatch'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make an simplified_name column in each of the 2 dataframes by setting all characters to lowercase and removing all the non [a-z ] characters and join on this column if this doesn't lead to collisions