# Filter dataframe with dictionary values while assigning dictionary keys to matching rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column 'Links' that contains the URLs to a few thousand online articles. There is one URL for each observation.

```
urls_list = ['http://www.ajc.com/news/world/atlan...',
             'http://www.seattletimes.com/sports/...',
             'https://www.cjr.org/q_and_a/washing...',
             'https://www.washingtonpost.com/grap...',
             'https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/01/...',
             'http://www.oregonlive.com/silicon-f...']

df = pd.DataFrame(urls_list,columns=['Links'])
```

I additionally have a dictionary that contains *publication names* as keys and *domain names* as values.

```
urls_dict = dict({'Atlanta Journal-Constitution':'ajc.com',
                  'The Washington Post':'washingtonpost.com',
                  'The New York Times':'nytimes.com'})
```

I'd like to filter the dataframe to get only those observations where the 'Links' column contains the domains in the dictionary values, while *at the same time* assigning the publication name in the dictionary keys to a new column 'Publication.' What I envisioned is using the below code to create the 'Publication' column then dropping `None`'s from that column to filter the dataframe after the fact.

```
pub_list = []

for row in df['Links']:
    for k,v in urls_dict.items():
        if row.find(v) > -1:
            publication = k
        else:
            publication = None
        pub_list.append(publication)
```

However, the list `pub_list` that I get in return - while appearing to do what I intended - is three times as long as my dataframe. Can someone suggest how to fix the above code? Or, alternatively, suggest a cleaner solution that can both (1) filter the 'Links' column of my dataframe using the dictionary values (domain names) while (2) creating a new 'Publication' column of the dictionary keys (publication names)? (Please note that the `df` is created here with only one column for brevity; the actual file will have many columns and thereby I have to be able to specify which column to filter on.)

**EDIT:** I wanted to give some clarification's given **RagingRoosevelt's** answer. I'd like to avoid using merging as some of the domains may not be exact matches. For example, with `ajc.com` I'd also like to be able to capture `myajc.com`, and with `washingtonpost.com` I'd want to get sub-domains like `live.washingtonpost.com` as well. Hence, I was hoping for a type of "find substring in string" solution with `str.contains()`, `find()`, or the `in` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using a nested dictionary comprehension (and alternatively, using a nested list comprehension) with some additional dataframe manipulation to clean up the columns and drop blank rows.

Using a **nested dictionary comprehension** (or, more specifically, a dictionary comprehension nested inside of a list comprehension):

```
df['Publication'] = [{k: k for k,v in urls_dict.items() if v in row} for row in df['Links']]

# Format the 'Publication' column to get rid of duplicate 'key' values
df['Publication'] = df['Publication'].astype(str).str.strip('{}').str.split(':',expand=True)[0]

# Remove blank rows from 'Publication' column
df = df[df['Publication'] != '']
```

Similarly, using a **nested list comprehension**:

```
# First converting dict to a list of lists 
urls_list_of_lists = list(map(list,urls_dict.items()))

# Nested list comprehension using 'in' operator 
df['Publication'] = [[item[0] for item in urls_list_of_lists if item[1] in row] for row in df['Links']]

# Format the 'Publication' column to get rid of duplicate brackets
df['Publication'] = df['Publication'].astype(str).str.strip('[]')

# Remove blank rows from 'Publication' column
df = df[df['Publication'] != '']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd do:

1. Use [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to add a new column to your dataframe that contains just the domain.
2. Use [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) (with the `how='inner'` option) to merge your two data frames on your domain field.

It's a bit dirty to use loops to do stuff to dataframes if they're just iterating over columns or rows and generally there's a DataFrame method that does the same thing more cleanly.

If you want, I can expand this with examples.

**edit** Here's what that would look like.  Note that I'm using rather terrible regex for domain capture.

```
def domain_extract(row):
    s = row['Links']
    p = r'(?:(?:\w+)?(?::\/\/)(?:www\.)?)?([A-z0-9.]+)\/.*'
    m = re.match(p, s)
    if m is not None:
        return m.group(1)
    else:
        return None

df['Domain'] = df.apply(domain_extract, axis=1)

dfo = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Atlanta Journal-Constitution', 'The Washington Post', 'The New York Times'], 'Domain': ['ajc.com', 'washingtonpost.com', 'nytimes.com']})

df.merge(dfo, on='Domain', how='inner')[['Links', 'Domain', 'Name']]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but I'd like to avoid using `merge` as some of the domains may not be _exact_ matches. For example, with `ajc.com` I'd also like to be able to capture `myajc.com`, and with `washingtonpost.com` I'd want to get sub-domains like `live.washingtonpost.com` as well. Hence, I was hoping for a type of "find substring in string" solution w/ `str.contains()` or `find()` for some added flexibility.

Comment: Looks like it should be possible to do fuzzy matching
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas