# Fuzzy matching between columns of different dataframes (of different lengths)

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-search

I see that it's relatively easy to do fuzzy matching between two columns of two dataframes of identical length [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas) but how to generalize to dataframes of different length?

Comment: Please look at how to provide a [mcve].