# How to do Zip code matching using pandas in a vectorised manner?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of containing zip codes like

```
zip_codes = pd.Series(['10001', '1020', '98068'])
```

Now I have to compare it against a master table containing all the US zip codes and create a a Boolean series stating if a match is found or not.

```
zip_master = pd.DataFrame([['98292', 'Lake Ketchum'], ['98068', 'Roslyn'], ['99013', 99013]], columns=['Zip Code', 'City Name'])
```

Is there a vectorised way to do this? I looked into series string methods [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling), but could not figure out if its the right thing to use.

EDIT 1: As per the comments - we can use the dataframe method [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

So my main initial question is answered.
I would like to extend this question little further. Is it possible to partial string matching in a vectorised way. Say I have a series  containing city names and I want to match it against City Name of zip master. ? I have seen string matching being used like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas)- But its not vectorised. Is there any efficient vectorised method for it

Should I use some other technique like cacheing or data base to get this done?

Comment: You can check `isin`.

Comment: `zip_codes.isin(zip_master['Zip Code'])`

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. This exactly what I want ! Do you have any suggestions for partial string matching. Say I have a series from containing city names and I want to match it against City Name of zip master. Is there any efficient vectorised method for it ? I have seen fuzzy matching being used - is there a vectorised implementation for the same in pandas?

Comment: @NisseEngström I have fixed it

Comment: for second requirement something like `zip_master.loc([zip_master['Roslyn']==98068)]`

Comment: or `zip_master[zip_master['City Name'].str.contains("Roslyn")==True]`

Comment: @pygo It would not match for 'New Jersy' if master zip record has 'New Jersey'. My data is coming from a user form, and may contain misspellings.

Comment: you can use `regex`  like `str.startswith(^Ne*y$)`   as it will meet New or  NEW and ending with Jersey or Jersy, i have not tested ths  but it works like this.

Comment: Yeah. That will work if I have only few comparisons to make. But i have thousands of rows that need to be compared against the master and hard-coded regex approach might not be the best solution.