# How to merge on approximate strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge 2 Data Frames on approximate country name with merge as of but i am getting the following error:

TypeError:'NoneType' object is not callable

Please see the illustrative code below:

```
cl =  {'Country' : ["Brazil", "US", "Russia"], 'BL?':['No', 'No','Yes']}
clist = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cl)

cd = {'Country' : ["Braizl", "us", "Rusia"]}
cdata  = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cd)

clist = clist.sort_values('Country')
cdata = cdata.sort_values('Country')


cdata = pd.merge_asof(cdata,clist,on='Country')
```

The expected result would merge the two dfs and the cdata df would have the 'BL?' column with YES/NO values.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `inplace=True` makes sort_values returns `None`, because you are specifying the method to do it inplace

Comment: True, I get a nonetype object is not callable now after removing the inplace

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: I think `merge_asof` only works with integers. If you wan't to find the closest a string is to another you could use the levenshtein distance, but I am not aware of any implementation of it in the Pandas library.

Comment: How would I apply it to 2 dicts?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas

Comment: It does not work for this, i have already seen this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you close but it will not be 100% accurate. You can use [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy#process). `fuzzywuzzy` uses Levenshtein distance to calculate the difference between two strings:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

# create a choice list
choices = clist['Country'].values.tolist()

# apply fuzzywuzzy to each row using lambda expression
cdata['Close Country'] = cdata['Country'].apply(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, choices)[0])

# merge
cdata.merge(clist, left_on='Close Country', right_on='Country')


  Country_x Close Country Country_y  BL?
0    Braizl        Brazil    Brazil   No
1     Rusia        Russia    Russia  Yes
2        us            US        US   No
```

You can even return the percent match and only keep values > n if you want to only keep matches say greater than 85%

## add percent match

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

# create a choice list
choices = clist['Country'].values.tolist()

# apply fuzzywuzzy to each row using lambda expression
cdata['Close Country'] = cdata['Country'].apply(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, choices))

# add percent match wiht apply
cdata[['Close Country', 'Percent Match']] = cdata['Close Country'].apply(pd.Series)

# merge
cdata.merge(clist, left_on='Close Country', right_on='Country')

  Country_x Close Country  Percent Match Country_y  BL?
0    Braizl        Brazil             83    Brazil   No
1     Rusia        Russia             91    Russia  Yes
2        us            US            100        US   No
```

you can do boolean indexing either before the merge to remove bad match then merge:

```
cdata[['Close Country', 'Percent Match']] = cdata['Close Country'].apply(pd.Series)
cdata = cdata[cdata['Percent Match']>85]
```

or you can do it after the merge:

```
merge = cdata.merge(clist, left_on='Close Country', right_on='Country')
merge[merge['Percent Match'] > 85]
```

`fuzzywuzzy` returns the percent match as part of the `process` function. In the first example I removed it by calling the first element of the tuple: `process.extractOne(x, choices)[0]`

Comment: Bravo! Thank you very much!

Comment: How can i return the % match?

Comment: @TPguru Do you want it as a new column?

Comment: Yes that would be great

Comment: Try replacing ```from fuzzywuzzy import process``` to ```from rapidfuzz import process```. You would see drastic execution time improvements with same results

Answer (score 1):

Given your example I came to a solution. This is not very pythonic but it works! (assuming you have a matching country name in `clist` for every `cdata` mispelled country)

```
def get_closest(x, column):
    tmp = 1000
    for i2, r2 in clist.iterrows():
        levenshtein = editdistance.eval(x,r2['Country'])
        if levenshtein <= tmp:
            tmp = levenshtein
            res = r2

    return res['BL?']

cdata['BL'] = cdata['Country'].apply(lambda x: get_closest(x, clist))
```

Output :

```
   Country   BL
0  Braizl   No
1      us   No
2   Rusia  Yes
```

I am using the [editdistance](https://pypi.org/project/editdistance/) library to compute the levenshtein distance.
You can install it with pip :

```
pip install editdistance
```

Comment: Well there should be two. Can you post what your code looks like ?