# Match rows by id value in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I need to match contacts in a database by how they were contacted by a unique ID number. I've created a very small mock dataframe below to help with a suggestion:

```
data = [
    ["email", "emailperson1@email.com", 1],
    ["phone", "555-555-1111", 1],
    ["slack", "secondpersonslack", 2],
    ["phone", "111-111-1111", 3],
]

data2 = [
    [1, "emailperson1@email.com", "555-555-1111", "slack1"],
    [2, "emailperson2@gmail.com", "555-555-2222", "secondpersonslack"],
    [3, "tomasconticello@gmail.com", "111-111-1111", "tomasslack"],
]

stackdata = pd.DataFrame(
    data, columns=["contact method", "from:", "column that I dont know how to make"]
)
stackdata2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=["id", "email", "phone", "slack"])
```

In my real dataset, what I want to fill out is the column 'column that I dont know how to make'.

So, take first contact method in stackdata in row one, which was an email address. This email lines up with ID 1 in stack2, so it would populate the column in the stackdata1 with "1".

I was thinking of some of kind of for loop like:

```
for i in stackdata['column that I dont know how to make']:
  if i matches one of the columns in any row, then populate column with id of that row
```

Thanks for any help and let me know if i can make this question easier to answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(stackdata)):
    stackdata['contact_id'][i] = str(stackdata2[(stackdata2['email'] == stackdata['from:'][i]) | (stackdata2['phone'] == stackdata['from:'][i]) | (stackdata2['slack'] == stackdata['from:'][i])]['id'].values).strip('[]')
```

`'contact_id'` is the column `'column that I dont know how to make'`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to `melt` the contact-method columns in the second DataFrame into a single column, and `merge` the result with the first DataFrame. By default, pandas merges on any and all same-named columns in left and right. ([From the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html): "If on is not passed and left_index and right_index are False, the intersection of the columns in the DataFrames and/or Series will be inferred to be the join keys.")

```
# Choose desired columns from your example data
df = stackdata[['contact method', 'from:']].copy()  

# Melt or "unpivot" the contact methods, renaming
# the resulting variable and value columns to match
# column names in stackdata
melted = pd.melt(stackdata2, 
                 id_vars='id', 
                 value_vars=['email', 'phone', 'slack'], 
                 value_name='from:', var_name='contact method')

# Merge with default arguments
pd.merge(df, melted)
  contact method                   from:  id
0          email  emailperson1@email.com   1
1          phone            555-555-1111   1
2          slack       secondpersonslack   2
3          phone            111-111-1111   3
```

Comment: thanks for answer! but part of the issue with that is that each contact method isn't always labeled accurately. like a slack contact might be "message". so melting would miss a lot of think. maybe if we could match with any similar column. how would that be done?

Comment: hmm... no out-of-the-box way that I know of, though this looks interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas