# how to drop duplicates after merging two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, drop-duplicates

I have two dataframes ,

```
A= 
ID compponent weight
12  Cap        0.4
12  Pump       183
12  label      0.05
14  cap        0.6 

B=
ID compponent_B weight_B
12  Cap_B       0.7
12  Pump_B       189
12  label      0.05
```

when i do merge of this two dataframes based on the ID as a key ,I get

```
ID component weight component_B  weight_B
12  Cap        0.4   Cap_B        0,7
12  Cap        0.4   Pump_B       189
12  Cap        0.4   label        0.05
12  Pump       183   Cap_B        0,7
12  Pump       183   Pump_B       189
14  Pump       183   label        0.05
...
```

I understand that the fact that i have One ID pour the 3 lines genrates 9 lines if i do the merge , but how can i only keep three lines without losing information ,if i do a drop_duplicates on Component i'll lose  informations about component_B. i want something like :

```
ID component weight  component_B  weight_B
12  Cap        0.4    Cap_B        0,7
12  Pump       183    Pump_B       189
12  labeL      0,05   label        0.05
```

anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: You should try doing merge based on ID and Component as it looks you really to do that not the merge based on ID only.

Comment: but the components aren't exactly the same

Comment: Are the format of component same i..e. Cap_B, Pump_B and label_B or Cap_B, Pump_B and label ?

Comment: It's different , i was thinking more of a solution using drop after the merge  cauz i have no other way to do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58025517/how-to-link-two-dataframes-based-on-the-string-similarity-of-one-column .. You can try this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a column with a [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) per ID to be able to `merge` on ID and this new column so like:

```
dfm = dfA.assign(cc=dfA.groupby('ID').cumcount())\
         .merge(dfB.assign(cc=dfB.groupby('ID').cumcount()), 
                on=['ID', 'cc'], how='outer')
print (dfm)
   ID compponent  weight  cc compponent_B  weight_B
0  12        Cap    0.40   0        Cap_B      0.70
1  12       Pump  183.00   1       Pump_B    189.00
2  12      label    0.05   2        label      0.05
3  14        cap    0.60   0          NaN       NaN
```

Comment: @chero maybe change the parameter how to 'inner' or 'left', depending on what you want to keep?

Comment: ur solution gaves me the 3 lines desired but i losted informations from the first dataframe , i only had  "label" combined with the three component_B (cap_B and Pump_B and label)

Comment: @chero hmm as you can see with the data you provided in your question it does not have the behavior you just say. in which condition you get label with the 3 components?