# Join Dataframes if column x string is in column y string

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to Join 2 dataframes based on if the values in Table A are in the values on Table B

```
df1={Table_A: ABC, BCD-1, BCD-2}
df2={Table_B: ABC-1, BCD-1, BCD-2}
```

The straight join below returns the following

```
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='Table_A',right_on='Table_B',how='outer')
```

[Post Join Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/327iA.png)

I'm trying to do something were it joins if df1.Table_A is in df2.Table_B

[Post Join Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TMdo.png)

This was what I was thinking bit obviously isn't working for me.

```
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=df1['Table_A'].isin(df2['Table_B']),how='outer')
```

Comment: change `how='right'` if you want keys from your right df only.

Answer (score 0):

This is fuzzy merging and I wrote a function for this: [`fuzzy_merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56315491/9081267):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

fuzzy_merge(df1,df2,'Table_A','Table_B')

  Table_A matches
0     ABC   ABC-1
1   BCD-1   BCD-1
2   BCD-2   BCD-2
```