# Replace elements in Pandas column which have a distance measure greater than a threshold

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Consider a dataframe :

```
company  |  label 

  comp1       fashion
  comp2       fashionitem
  comp3       fashionable
  comp4       auto
  comp5       autoindustry
  comp6       automobile
  comp6       food
  comp7       delivery
```

I want to clean-up the labels a bit, and I am using a string distance for that:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def distance(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

The question is, how can I write a function that applies the `distance` function between any two elements on the `label` column and, at the end, replaces all similar elements (distance above a certain threshold) with the shortest string?

The result should be something like:

```
company  |  label 

  comp1       fashion
  comp2       fashion
  comp3       fashion
  comp4       auto
  comp5       auto
  comp6       auto
  comp6       food
  comp7       delivery
```

I am thinking of performing 2 for loops, but my dataset may be quite large, is there an efficient way of doing this?

EDIT: While reading the below replies, I realize I made a mistake. The overall number of entries (number of companies) is large, BUT the overall number of unique labels is small, less than 1000. One could apply `df.label(unique)` and work with that, I guess.

Comment: How large is your dataset?

Comment: @Erfan right now it "only" has around 500k entries, but I think it could go to maybe 2-3 million entries in total.

Comment: Are you willing to accept approximate solution, the exact solution would take 500_000 ^ 2 operations at least. Does the similar elements always share a common prefix?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, I would love to have an exact function, that works for a small number of different labels as well (  < 1000). I made a correction in the question above, as I realize the number of different labels is small.

Comment: In your above example fashion, fashionable, fashionitem form a cluster therefore all of them must be replaced by the one shortest of them?

Comment: @DanielMesejo yep.

Comment: [This fuzzy_merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas/56315491#56315491) function I wrote can help you. I came quite close, but couldn't get your exact expected output. Start of with a self join `fuzzy_merge(df, df, 'label', 'label', threshold=50, limit=5)` and proceed from there. Also play around with the `threshold` argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Idea**

The idea for this approach is to build an adjacency matrix from the threshold (ed) ratio matrix. From the adjacency matrix build a graph, and from it get the connected components (clusters). Getting to the desired output can be tricky, but it can be achieved with an (absolute) threshold of 0.49.

**Setup**

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['comp1', 'fashion'],
                        ['comp2', 'fashionitem'],
                        ['comp3', 'fashionable'],
                        ['comp4', 'auto'],
                        ['comp5', 'autoindustry'],
                        ['comp6', 'automobile'],
                        ['comp6', 'food'],
                        ['comp7', 'delivery']], columns=['company', 'label'])


def distance(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

**Code**

```
# get unique labels
labels = df['label'].unique()

# compute ratios
result = np.array([[distance(li, lj) for lj in labels] for li in labels])

# set diagonal to zero
result[np.arange(8), np.arange(8)] = 0

# build adjacency matrix
adjacency_matrix = (result > 0.49).astype(int)

# create graph
dg = nx.from_numpy_array(adjacency_matrix, create_using=nx.Graph)

# create mapping dictionary from connected components
mapping = {}
for component in nx.connected_components(dg):
    group = labels[np.array(list(component))]
    value = min(group, key=len)
    mapping.update({label: value for label in group})

result = df.assign(label=df.label.map(mapping))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  company     label
0   comp1   fashion
1   comp2   fashion
2   comp3   fashion
3   comp4      auto
4   comp5      auto
5   comp6      auto
6   comp6      food
7   comp7  delivery
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting approach, but I have applied it to my actual dataframe and get the label 'TV" for everyone on the new column.

Comment: What threshold did you use?

Comment: 0.49, and it returns "vi" and 0.60 returns "tv". Don't really understand why.

Comment: Try to see what are the values of component, by what you say it seems there is only one connected component.

Comment: Seems to work well for a thresh of 0.8. I will accept this answer, thanks.