# Trying to match up two df's based on three common columns with none of them being identical

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, sequencematcher

I have two df's

df1

```
    date            League                                 teams
0   201902272215    brazil cup                             foz do iguacu fcceara ce
1   201902272300    colombia primera a                     deportes tolimaatletico bucaramanga
2   201902272300    brazil campeonato gaucho 2nd division  ypiranga rsuniao frederiquense
3   201902272300    brazil campeonato gaucho 2nd division  esportivo rstupi rs
4   201902272300    brazil campeonato gaucho 2nd division  sao paulo rsgremio esportivo bage
14  201902280000    four nations women tournament (in usa) usa (w)japan (w)
25  201902280030    bolivia professional football league   real potosibolivar
```

df2

```
    date            league                     teams
0   201902280000    womens international       usa womenjapan women
1   201902280000    brazil amazonense          sul america ecrio negro am
2   201902280030    bolivia apertura           real potosibolivar
3   201902280030    brazil campeonato paulista palmeirasituano
4   201902280030    copa sudamericana          racing clubcorinthians
```

The result I would want is all the rows from df2 that are near matches with df1

```
    date            league                     teams                      near_match
0   201902280000    womens international       usa womenjapan women       1
1   201902280000    brazil amazonense          sul america ecrio negro am 0
2   201902280030    bolivia apertura           real potosibolivar         1
3   201902280030    brazil campeonato paulista palmeirasituano            0
4   201902280030    copa sudamericana          racing clubcorinthians     0
```

I have tried to use a variation of a for loop using `SequenceMatcher` and setting the threshold to a match of above 0.8, but haven't had any luck.

```
df_1['merge_teams'] = df_1['teams'] # we will use these as the merge keys
df_1['merge_date'] = df_1['date']
# df_1['merge_league'] = df_1['league']


for teams_1, date_1, league_1 in df_1[['teams','date']].values:
    for ixb, (teams_1, teams_2) in enumerate(df_2[['teams','date']].values):
        if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,teams_1,teams_2).ratio() > .8:
            df_2.ix[ixb,'merge_teams'] = teams_1 # creates a merge key in df_2
        if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,date_1, date_2).ratio() > .8:
            df_2.ix[ixb,'merge_date'] = date_1 # creates a merge key in df_2

# This should rturn all rows where teams,date and league all match by over 80%
# This is just for teams and date, I want to include league as well
```

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at my [fuzzy_merging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56315491/9081267) answer

Comment: how would I go about doing it across multiple columns?