# Search column for a string and Classify them with a dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

I've imported a spreadsheet I'd exported from Linkedin of my connections and want to categorize people's positions at different  levels.

So, I've created a dictionary with the terms to look up each position level.

A first version of the dictionary would be:

```
dicpositions = {'0 - CEO, Founder': ['CEO', 'Founder', 'Co-Founder', 'Cofounder', 'Owner'],
                '1 - Director of': ['Director', 'Head'], 
                '2 - Manager': ['Manager', 'Administrador'], 
                '3 - Engenheiro': ['Engenheiro', 'Engineering'], 
                '4 - Consultor': ['Consultor', 'Consultant'], 
                '5 - Estagiário': ['Estagiário', 'Intern'], 
                '6 - Desempregado': ['Self-Employed', 'Autônomo'], 
                '7 - Professor': ['Professor', 'Researcher'] }
```

And I need a code to read each position in my spreadsheet, check if there is any of these terms and return the equivalent key in another specific column.

A sample data of the dataframe i'm reading would be:

```
sample = pd.Series(data = (['(blank)'], ['Estagiário'], ['Professor', 'Adjunto'], 
                           ['CEO', 'and', 'Founder'], ['Engenheiro', 'de', 'Produção'], 
                           ['Consultant'], ['Founder', 'and', 'CTO'], 
                           ['Intern'], ['Manager', 'Specialist'], 
                           ['Administrador', 'de', 'Novos', 'Negócios'], 
                           ['Administrador', 'de', 'Serviços']))
```

Which Returns:

```
0                                [(blank)]
1                             [Estagiário]
2                     [Professor, Adjunto]
3                      [CEO, and, Founder]
4               [Engenheiro, de, Produção]
5                             [Consultant]
6                      [Founder, and, CTO]
7                                 [Intern]
8                    [Manager, Specialist]
9     [Administrador, de, Novos, Negócios]
10           [Administrador, de, Serviços]
dtype: object
```

I've done the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
plan = pd.read_excel('SpreadSheet Name.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Positions')

list0 = ['CEO', 'Founder', 'Co-Founder', 'Cofounder', 'Owner']
list1 = ['Director', 'Head']
list2 = ['Manager', 'Administrador']   
listgeral = [dic0, dic1, dic2]

def in_list(list_to_search,terms_to_search):     
    results = [item for item in list_to_search if item in terms_to_search]
    if len(results) > 0:
        return '0 - CEO, Founder'        
    else:
        pass
plan['PositionLevel'] = plan['Position'].str.split().apply(lambda x: in_list(x, listgeral[0]))
```

Actual output:

```
                                          Position           PositionLevel
0                                        '(blank)'                None
1                                     'Estagiário'                None
2                              'Professor Adjunto'                None
3                                'CEO and Founder'         '0 - CEO, Founder'
4                         'Engenheiro de produção'                None
5                                     'Consultant'                None
6                                'Founder and CTO'         '0 - CEO, Founder'
7                                         'Intern'                None
8                             'Manager Specialist'                None
9                'Administrador de Novos Negócios'                None
```

Expected output:

```
                                            Position         PositionLevel
0                                          '(blank)'              None
1                                       'Estagiário'       '5 - Estagiário'
2                                'Professor Adjunto'       '7 - Professor'
3                                  'CEO and Founder'      '0 - CEO, Founder'
4                           'Engenheiro de produção'       '3 - Engenheiro'
5                                       'Consultant'       '4 - Consultor'
6                                  'Founder and CTO'      '0 - CEO, Founder'
7                                           'Intern'       '5 - Estagiário'
8                               'Manager Specialist'        '2 - Manager'
9                  'Administrador de Novos Negócios'        '2 - Manager'
```

First I was planning to run that code for every list inside my `listgeral`, but I coundn't do so. Then I started to believe it would be better to apply this one for a big dictionary, just as the `dicpositions` from the beginning of the question, and the return the key of the term.

I've tried to apply the following code to this program:

```
dictest = {'0 - CEO, Founder': ['CEO', 'Founder', 'Co-Founder', 'Cofounder', 'Owner'], 
           '1 - Director of': ['Director', 'Head'], 
           '2 - Manager': ['Manager', 'Administrador']}

def in_dic (x, dictest):
    for key in dictest:
        for elem in dictest[key]:
            if elem == x:
                return key
    return False
```

Where the output from `in_dic('CEO', dictest)` Is `'0 - CEO, Founder'`

And, for example, the output from `in_dic('Banana', dictest)` is `False`

But I couldn't advance from it and apply this function `in_dic()` to my problem.

I would really appreciate anybody's help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty to refactor your input a bit, but here's what I've got (it might be slightly over-engineered). In short, we use a library called [jellyfish](https://pypi.org/project/jellyfish/) (`pip3 install jellyfish`, code taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37505425/1531637) answer) to do fuzzy string-matching to match positions in your excel sheet with positions in your `dicpositions`, then just map those to the category in the same dict. Here's the imports and the matching function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import jellyfish


# Function for fuzzy-matching strings
def get_closest_match(x, list_strings):
    best_match = None
    highest_jw = 0

    # Keep an eye out for "blank" values, they can be strings, e.g. "(blank)", or e.g. NaN values
    no_values = ["(blank)", np.nan, None]
    if x in no_values:
        return "(blank)"

    # Find which string most closely matches our input and return it
    for current_string in list_strings:
        current_score = jellyfish.jaro_winkler(x, current_string)

        if current_score > highest_jw:
            highest_jw = current_score
            best_match = current_string

    return best_match
```

Alright, and here's your `dicpositions`, which I translate to a long-format DataFrame for convenience:

```
# Translations between keywords and their category, as dict, as provided in question
dicpositions = {'0 - CEO, Founder': ['CEO', 'Founder', 'Co-Founder', 'Cofounder', 'Owner'],
                '1 - Director of': ['Director', 'Head'],
                '2 - Manager': ['Manager', 'Administrador'],
                '3 - Engenheiro': ['Engenheiro', 'Engineering'],
                '4 - Consultor': ['Consultor', 'Consultant'],
                '5 - Estagiário': ['Estagiário', 'Intern'],
                '6 - Desempregado': ['Self-Employed', 'Autônomo'],
                '7 - Professor': ['Professor', 'Researcher'],
                'Not found"': ["(blank)"]  # <-- I added this to deal with blank values
}

# Let's expand the dict above to a DF, which makes for easier merging later
positions = []
aliases = []
for key, val in dicpositions.items():
    for v in val:
        positions.append(key)
        aliases.append(v)
# This will serve as our mapping table
lookup_table = pd.DataFrame({
    "position": positions,
    "alias": aliases
})
print(lookup_table)
```

Instead of being a dictionary, it's a long-format DataFrame. This format makes it really easy to match categories with various keywords later:

```
            position          alias
0   0 - CEO, Founder            CEO
1   0 - CEO, Founder        Founder
2   0 - CEO, Founder     Co-Founder
3   0 - CEO, Founder      Cofounder
4   0 - CEO, Founder          Owner
5    1 - Director of       Director
6    1 - Director of           Head
7        2 - Manager        Manager
8        2 - Manager  Administrador
9     3 - Engenheiro     Engenheiro
10    3 - Engenheiro    Engineering
11     4 - Consultor      Consultor
12     4 - Consultor     Consultant
13    5 - Estagiário     Estagiário
14    5 - Estagiário         Intern
15  6 - Desempregado  Self-Employed
16  6 - Desempregado       Autônomo
17     7 - Professor      Professor
18     7 - Professor     Researcher
19        Not found"        (blank)
```

Let's test some input and see how the matching works. We check every string in your input with the strings in the `alias` column, and return whichever value in the `alias` column most closely match our input data (we'll use this again later, to find the category, or `position`):

```
# Test input, as a list, you might have to wrangle it from your format to a list, though
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"test_position": ["(blank)", 'Estagiário', 'Professor Adjunto', 'CEO and Founder', 'Engenheiro de produção', 'Consultant', 'Founder and CTO', 'Intern', 'Manager Specialist', 'Administrador de Novos Negócios']})

# Match our test input with our mapping table, create a new column 'best_match' representing the value in our mapping table that most closely matches our input
test_df["best_match"] = test_df.test_position.map(lambda x: get_closest_match(x, lookup_table.alias))
print(test_df)
```

A new column is added to our `test_df`, indicating which `alias` in our lookup table is most similar to our `test_position` input:

```
                    test_position     best_match
0                          (blank)        (blank)
1                       Estagiário     Estagiário
2                Professor Adjunto      Professor
3                  CEO and Founder            CEO
4           Engenheiro de produção     Engenheiro
5                       Consultant     Consultant
6                  Founder and CTO        Founder
7                           Intern         Intern
8               Manager Specialist        Manager
9  Administrador de Novos Negócios  Administrador
```

To end up with the category, we simply merge our `best_match` column in our testing data with the `alias` column of our lookup table:

```
result = test_df.merge(lookup_table, left_on="best_match", right_on="alias", how="left")
```

Resulting in this:

```
                    test_position     best_match          alias          position
0                          (blank)        (blank)        (blank)         Not found
1                       Estagiário     Estagiário     Estagiário    5 - Estagiário
2                Professor Adjunto      Professor      Professor     7 - Professor
3                  CEO and Founder            CEO            CEO  0 - CEO, Founder
4           Engenheiro de produção     Engenheiro     Engenheiro    3 - Engenheiro
5                       Consultant     Consultant     Consultant     4 - Consultor
6                  Founder and CTO        Founder        Founder  0 - CEO, Founder
7                           Intern         Intern         Intern    5 - Estagiário
8               Manager Specialist        Manager        Manager       2 - Manager
9  Administrador de Novos Negócios  Administrador  Administrador       2 - Manager
```

Comment: Plasma, Thank you so much! It worked pretty well to my spreadsheet! I still have to complete better the ```dicpositions```, and then do more tests. But for now it's working perfectly, and it's quite scalable!! I'm really thankful for your help!