# Check if there is a similar string in the same column

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-search

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1             col2
 A        'the value is zero'
 B        'this is a cat'
 C        'the value is one'
 D        'nothing is here'
 E        'the colour is blue'
 F        'this is dog'
 G        'empty sequence'
 H        'the colour is red'
 I        'the colour is green'         1
```

Now I want the similar kind of strings as flagged as 1 and others as zero, so the final data frame should look like,

```
col1             col2                 col1
 A        'the value is zero'           1
 B        'this is a cat'               1
 C        'the value is one'            1
 D        'nothing is here'             0
 E        'the colour is blue'          1
 F        'this is dog'                 1
 G        'empty sequence'              0
 H        'the colour is red'           1
 I        'the colour is green'         1
```

The 0 and 1 can be obtained using SequenceMatcher(SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2).ratio()) function and with some threshold value we can make it to zero or one.

But if I use for loops to find the similarity between each other then it will take longer time to execute. Looking for some pandas shortcuts/pythonic way to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similarly to [is it possible to do fuzzy match merge with python pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908516/9698684),
we can use `difflib` and check if we find more than 1 similar string (to exclude its own) by looking at the length of the list returned by [`difflib.get_close_matches`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches):

```
import difflib

df['col1'] = [(len(difflib.get_close_matches(x, df['col2'], cutoff=0.7))>1)*1 
              for x in df['col2']]
```

---

```
print(df)

   col1                            col2
0     1             'the value is zero'
1     1                 'this is a cat'
2     1              'the value is one'
3     0               'nothing is here'
4     1            'the colour is blue'
5     1                   'this is dog'
6     0                'empty sequence'
7     1             'the colour is red'
8     1           'the colour is green'
```

---

### Similarity matrix based on [fuzzy matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching)

One could also be interested in obtaining a similarity matrix setting all values in a pivoted column to `1` if the strings are similar. For this we could proceed similarly as above, but keeping the entire list, exploding it and pivoting the resulting dataframe with [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df['sim'] = [difflib.get_close_matches(x, df['col2'], cutoff=0.7)  for x in df['col2']]
sim_df = df.explode('sim')
pd.crosstab(sim_df.col2, sim_df.sim)

sim             empty sequence  nothing is here  the colour is blue... the value is zero  this is a cat  this is dog
col2
empty sequence      1                0                     0         ...        0                   0            0
nothing is here     0                1                     0         ...        0                   0            0
the colour is blue  0                0                     1         ...        0                   0            0
the colour is green 0                0                     1         ...        0                   0            0
the colour is red   0                0                     1         ...        0                   0            0
the value is one    0                0                     0         ...        1                   0            0
the value is zero   0                0                     0         ...        1                   0            0
this is a cat       0                0                     0         ...        0                   1            1
this is dog         0                0                     0         ...        0                   1            1
```