# Find All Variation Of A Word In A Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

How to identify all the variation of a word in a column_one, and then fill a value in other column, , columns_two, whenever a variation of that word is found?

E.g. Fill column `value` with P, whenever a variation of "PHIADELPHIA" is found, and fill with I, whenever a variation of "ILLINOIS" if found.

| place | value |
| --- | --- |
| PHIADELPHIA |  |
| PHIALDELPHIA |  |
| PHIDELPHIA |  |
| illinois |  |
| PHIELADELPHIA |  |
| PHIILADELPHIA |  |
| illinoi |  |
| PHILA |  |
| PHILA. |  |
| PHILAD |  |
| PHILADALPHIA |  |
| PHILADELPHIA |  |
| PHILADELAPHIA |  |
| PHILADELHIA |  |
| PHILADELHPIA |  |
| PHILADELLPHIA |  |
| PHILADELPHIA |  |
| PHILADELPH |  |
| PHILADELPHA |  |
| PHILADELPHAI |  |
| PHILADELPHI |  |
| PHILADELPHIA |  |

Fuzzy Matching, Levenshtein distance, etc

### Input String:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

place = ['PHIADELPHIA','PHIALDELPHIA','PHIDELPHIA','illinois','PHIELADELPHIA','PHIILADELPHIA','illinoi','PHILA','PHILA.','PHILAD','PHILADALPHIA','PHILADELPHIA','PHILADELAPHIA','PHILADELHIA','PHILADELHPIA','PHILADELLPHIA','PHILADELPHIA','PHILADELPH','PHILADELPHA','PHILADELPHAI','PHILADELPHI','PHILADELPHIA']
value=[np.nan]*len(place)
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(place,value), columns=["place", "value"])
df
```

Comment: I see you have fuzzywuzzy in your tags. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have checked `fuzzywuzzy`, however, need help in filling the vlaues in `value` column, whenever a variation of word1 or word2 is encountered. How to implement that logic is the main concern @CaptainCaveman

Comment: Does something like this help? `df.loc[df["place"].isin(["PHIADELPHIA", "PHILA"]), "value"] = "Philadelphia"`. The list should have all possibilities you found for Philadelphia. Also, you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987641/check-if-there-is-a-similar-string-in-the-same-column)

Answer (score 0):

A solution using fuzzywuzzy

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

threshold = 50
df['value'] = df['place'].apply(lambda x: 'P' if fuzz.token_set_ratio(x, 'Philadelphia') >= threshold else 'I' if fuzz.token_set_ratio(x, 'ILLINOIS') >= threshold else None)
```