# Comparing strings to assign a label

Tags: python, string, pandas

I would like to classify elements in rows (I am using pandas data frame) based on a list of strings:

```
list_topics=['orange', 'sports', 'technology', 'apple pie','fruits']
```

I want to see if websites contains one of that string in order to classify them.

For example:

```
 Website
www.apple.com
www.orange_is_the_new_black.co.uk
...
www.mitapple.com
```

These elements are stored in a row (row[0]).
I have tried as follows:

```
    writer = csv.writer(f_output, lineterminator='\n')
    reader = csv.reader(f_input)

    header = next(reader)
    header.append('Classification')
    writer.writerow(header)

    for row in reader:
        check_el = ['not classified']
        for x in list_topics:
            if row[0].str.contains[x]:
                check_el[0] = x
        writer.writerow(row + match)
```

However it returns only not classified, rather than (expected output):

```
  Website                                Topics
www.apple.com                            apple
www.orange_is_the_new_black.co.uk        orange
...                                      ...
www.mitapple.com                         apple
```

Could you please tell me how to compare each row to strings in the list and see if the row contains one of that string?

Thanks

Comment: I recognise this question. What happened last time?

Comment: It isn't clear to me, are you using Pandas or the CSV module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first flatten your list of topics by splitting the inner strings in a list comprehension, and then use `str.extract` to find matches with the items in the list:

```
l = [j for i in list_topics for j in i.split()]
df['Topics'] = df.Website.str.extract(rf"({'|'.join(l)})")
```

---

```
print(df)

                             Website  Topics
0                      www.apple.com   apple
1  www.orange_is_the_new_black.co.uk  orange
2                   www.mitapple.com   apple
```

---

Since it seems that the strings in the list to match could be slightly different, I'd suggest you to look into fuzzy searching too. For this case, you could use `fuzzy_merge` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908516/9698684) to get a similar result:

```
df_topics = pd.DataFrame(list_topics, columns=['topics'])

fuzzy_merge(df, df_topics, left_on='Website', right_on='topics', how='left', cutoff=0.25)

                             Website  Topics     topics
0                      www.apple.com   apple  apple pie
1  www.orange_is_the_new_black.co.uk  orange     orange
2                   www.mitapple.com   apple        NaN
```