# How can I merge these two datasets on 'Name' and 'Year'?

Tags: python, pandas, difflib

I am new in this field and stuck on this problem. I have two datasets

1. `all_batsman_df`, this df has 5 columns`('years','team','pos','name','salary')`

```
       years    team    pos name            salary
0       1991    SF      1B  Will Clark      3750000.0
1       1991    NYY     1B  Don Mattingly   3420000.0
2       1991    BAL     1B  Glenn Davis     3275000.0
3       1991    MIL     DH  Paul Molitor    3233333.0
4       1991    TOR     3B  Kelly Gruber    3033333.0
```

2. `all_batting_statistics_df`, this df has 31 columns

```
    Year    Rk  Name    Age Tm  Lg  G   PA  AB  R   ... SLG OPS OPS+    TB  GDP HBP SH  SF  IBB Pos Summary
0   1988    1   Glen Davis  22  SDP NL  37  89  83  6   ... 0.289   0.514   48.0    24  1   1   0   1   1   987
1   1988    2   Jim Acker   29  ATL NL  21  6   5   0   ... 0.400   0.900   158.0   2   0   0   0   0   0   1
2   1988    3   Jim Adduci* 28  MIL AL  44  97  94  8   ... 0.383   0.641   77.0    36  1   0   0   3   0   7D/93
3   1988    4   Juan Agosto*    30  HOU NL  75  6   5   0   ... 0.000   0.000   -100.0  0   0   0   1   0   0   1
4   1988    5   Luis Aguayo 29  TOT MLB 99  260 237 21  ... 0.354   0.663   88.0    84  6   1   1   1   3   564
```

I want to merge these two datasets on `'year', 'name'`. But the problem is, these both data frames has different names like in the first dataset, it has name `'Glenn Davis'` but in second dataset it has `'Glen Davis'`.

Now, I want to know that How can I merge both of them using `difflib` library even it has different names?
Any help will be appreciated ...
Thanks in advance.

I have used this code which I got in a question asked at this platform but it is not working for me. I am adding a new column after matching names in both of the datasets. I know this is not a good approach. Kindly suggest, If i can do it in a better way.

```
df_a = all_batting_statistics_df
df_b = all_batters
df_a = df_a.astype(str)
df_b = df_b.astype(str)

df_a['merge_year'] = df_a['Year'] # we will use these as the merge keys
df_a['merge_name'] = df_a['Name']

for comp_a, addr_a in df_a[['Year','Name']].values:
    for ixb, (comp_b, addr_b) in enumerate(df_b[['years','name']].values):
        if cdifflib.CSequenceMatcher(None,comp_a,comp_b).ratio() > .6:
            df_b.loc[ixb,'merge_year'] = comp_a # creates a merge key in df_b
        if cdifflib.CSequenceMatcher(None,addr_a, addr_b).ratio() > .6:
            df_b.loc[ixb,'merge_name'] = addr_a # creates a merge key in df_b


merged_df = pd.merge(df_a,df_b,on=['merge_name','merge_years'],how='inner')
```

Comment: If you know what the names are supposed to be, then first, clean your dataset

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], and provide a [mcve] as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```py
import difflib
df_b['name'] = df_b['name'].apply(lambda x: \
    difflib.get_close_matches(x, df_a['name'])[0])
```

to replace names in `df_b` with closest match from `df_a`, then do your merge.  See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas).

Answer (score 0):

**Let me get to your problem by assuming that you have to make a data set with 2 columns and the 2 columns being 1. 'year' and 2. 'name'
okay**

**1. we will 1st rename all the names which are wrong**
I hope you know all the wrong names from `all_batting_statistics_df` [using this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

`all_batting_statistics_df.replace(regex=r'^Glen.$', value='Glenn Davis')`

once you have corrected all the spellings, choose the smaller one which has the names you know, so it doesn't take long

**2. we need both data sets to have the same columns i.e. only 'year' and 'name'**
[use this to drop the columns we don't need](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

`all_batsman_df_1 = all_batsman_df.drop(['team','pos','salary'])`

`all_batting_statistics_df_1 = all_batting_statistics_df.drop(['Rk','Name','Age','Tm','Lg','G','PA','AB','R','Summary'], axis=1)`

I cannot see all the 31 columns so I left them, you have to add to the above code

**3. we need to change the column names to look the same i.e. 'year' and 'name'** using [python dataframe rename](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-dataframe-rename/)

`df_new_1 = all_batting_statistics_df(colums={'Year': 'year', 'Name':'name'})`

**4. next, to merge them**

[we will use this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

`all_batsman_df.merge(df_new_1, left_on='year', right_on='name')`

**FINAL THOUGHTS:**
If you don't want to do all this find a way to export the data set to google sheets or microsoft excel and use edit them with those advanced software, if you like `pandas` then its not that difficult you will find a way, all the best!