# Fuzzy Match two dataframe based on list value column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

I have two Dataframes that I am trying to merge by match to values in a column. The column to match are header1 in Df1 and header2 in Df2 (the value is list). I am looking for an adapted approach.

```
Df1:                                          Df2:
|--------------|---------------|              |--------------|------------------------|       
|      id_1    |     header1   |              |      id_2    |    header2             |
|--------------|---------------|              |--------------|------------------------|
|      112     |      item1    |              |      32      |['item1','item2',...]   |
|--------------|---------------|              |--------------|------------------------|
|      56      |      mass     | 
|--------------|---------------|
```

Wanted results:

```
Df_merged:                                       
|--------------|---------------|--------------|------------------------|       
|      id_1    |     header1   |      id_2    |    header2             |
|--------------|---------------|--------------|------------------------|
|      112     |      item1    |      32      |['item1','item2',...]   |
|--------------|---------------|--------------|------------------------|
```

Does anyone know how to merge these two dataframe ?. I have absolutely no idea how to handle this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with reassign `header2` to `header1` for avoid lost original column `header2` and then use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2.assign(header1 = df2['header2']).explode('header1'), on='header1')
```

Comment: Thank you ! this is what I need.

Comment: @elitebook190 - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Comment: I have another question if i want to use the fuzz.ratio of the string with fuzzywuzzy ? any idea

Comment: @elitebook190 - Then is possible check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas)

Comment: OK, thank you! So Sorry Another question: how about list in header1 and list in header 2. check if the common element exists.

Comment: @elitebook190 - Use `df = df1.assign(new= df1['header1']).explode('new').merge(df2.assign(new= df2['header2']).explode('new'), on='new')`

Comment: Me again you think difflib is more useful with 0.95 ratio?