# Python: Merging two columns of two different pandas dataframe using string matching

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to perform string matching between two pandas dataframe.

```
df_1:
ID   Text           Text_ID
1    Apple            53
2    Banana           84
3    Torent File      77

df_2: 
ID   File_name      
22   apple_mask.txt
23   melon_banana.txt
24   Torrent.pdf
25   Abc.ppt
```

**Objective:** I want to populate the `Text_ID` against `File_name` in df_2 if the string in `df_1['Text'] matches with df_2['File_name']. If no matches found then populate the df_2[`Text_ID`] as -1. So the resultant` df` looks like

```
ID   Flie_name           Text_ID
22   apple_mask.txt        53
23   melon_banana.txt      84
24   Torrent.pdf           77          
25   Abc.ppt               -1
```

I have tried this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas), but it is giving a column where File_name wise fuzz score is listed.

I am trying out a non fuzzy way. Please see below the code snippets:

```
text_ls = df_1['Text'].tolist()
file_ls = df_2['File_name'].tolist()
text_id = []
for i,j in zip(text_ls,file_ls):
  if str(j) in str(i):
    t_i = df_1.loc[df_1['Text']==i,'Text_ID']
    text_id.append(t_i)
  else:
    t_i = -1
    text_id.append(t_i)
df_2['Text_ID'] = text_id
```

But I am getting  a blank `text_id` list.

Can anybody provide some clue on this? I am OK to use fuzzywuzzy as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with the following code:

```
df2['Text_ID'] = -1    # set -1 by default for all the file names
for _,file_name in df2.iterrows():
    for _, text in df1.iterrows():     
        if text[0].lower() in file_name[0]:  # compare strings
            df2.loc[df2.File_name == file_name[0],'Text_ID'] = text[1] # assaign the Text_ID from df1 in df2
            break
```

Keep in mind:

- String comparison: As it is now working, `apple` and `banana` are contained in `apple_mask.txt` and `melon_banana.txt`, but `torrent file` is not in `torrent.pdf`. Consider redefining the string comparison.
- `df.iterrows()` returns two values, the `index` of the row and the `values` of the row, in this case I have replaced the index by `_` since it is not necessary to solve this problem

result:

```
df2
          File_name  Text_ID
0   apple_mask.text       53
1  melon_banana.txt       84
2       Torrent.pdf       -1
3           Abc.ppt       -1
```

Comment: if my answer was useful, can you mark it as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
text_ls = df_1['Text'].tolist()
file_ls = df_2['File_name'].tolist()
text_id = []
for i,j in zip(text_ls,file_ls):
      if j.lower().find(i.lower()) == -1:
        t_i = -1
        df_2.loc[df_2['File_name']==j,'Text_ID']=t_i
      else:
        t_i = df_1.loc[df_1['Text']==i,'Text_ID']
        df_2.loc[df_2['File_name']==j,'Text_ID']=t_i
```

Comment: Not quite sure about this line `if j.find(i) == -1:`. Please note there is no entry in df_2 as -1. Also you seemed to have missed the fact that `df_1['Text']` and `df_2['File_name']` are not exactly same.

Comment: Refer following answer for further clarification.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27138045/3417134

Comment: I have updated the code to convert df_1['Text'] and df_2['File_name'] to lower just for sake to comparison.

Comment: Your method might fail, if there are (1) blanks in df_2 (2) repeat of same file name in df_2. I just checked with my actual example and it is performing correct for the 1st match.