# find all - to find all occurrence of matching pattern one column of a data frame to other and get the corresponding value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, findall

I am working on a requirement, there are 2 CSV as below -

CSV.csv

```
    Short Description                                                    Category
    Device is DOWN!                                                      Server Down
    CPU Warning Monitoron  XSSXSXSXSXSX.com                              CPU Utilization
    CPU Warning Monitoron  XSSXSXSXSXSX.com                              CPU Utilization
    CPU Warning Monitoron  XSSXSXSXSXSX.com                              CPU Utilization
    CPU Warning Monitoron  XSSXSXSXSXSX.com                              CPU Utilization
    Device Performance Alerts was triggered on Physical memory           Memory Utilization
    Device Performance Alerts was triggered on Physical memory           Memory Utilization
    Device Performance Alerts was triggered on Physical memory           Memory Utilization
    Disk Space Is Lowon ;E:                                              Disk Space Utilization
    Disk Space Is Lowon;C:                                               Disk Space Utilization
    Network Interface Down                                               Interface Down


and reference.csv

    Category                         Complexity
    Server Down                      Simple
    Network Interface down           Complex
    Drive Cleanup Windows            Medium
    CPU Utilization                  Medium
    Memory Utilization               Medium
    Disk Space Utilization Unix      Simple
    Windows Service Restart          Medium
    UNIX Service Restart             Medium
    Web Tomcat Instance Restart      Simple

Expected Output

Short Description                                                    Category                    Complexity
Device is DOWN!                                                      Server Down                 Simple
CPU Warning Monitoron  XSSXSXSXSXSX.com                              CPU Utilization             Medium
CPU Warning Monitoron  XSSXSXSXSXSX.com                              CPU Utilization             Medium
CPU Warning Monitoron  XSSXSXSXSXSX.com                              CPU Utilization             Medium
CPU Warning Monitoron  XSSXSXSXSXSX.com                              CPU Utilization             Medium
Device Performance Alerts was triggered on Physical memory           Memory Utilization          Medium
Device Performance Alerts was triggered on Physical memory           Memory Utilization          Medium
Device Performance Alerts was triggered on Physical memory           Memory Utilization          Medium
Disk Space Is Lowon ;E:                                              Disk Space Utilization      Medium
Disk Space Is Lowon;C:                                               Disk Space Utilization      Medium
Network Interface Down                                               Interface Down              Complex
```

Now, I need query `CSV1.csv` and pick values of `'Category'` and find for all possible match in `Category` column of `reference.csv` and get the corresponding `'Complexity'` from `reference.csv` and put the data against each category of `CSV1.csv`.

I am using find.all to achive this. I am unable to do it as expected. Is there any better way to achieve the same.

I tried using `disct` functions, that did not give result as expected.

Comment: Please add possible inputs and the expected output

Comment: @jezrael - I have explored `merge` however it looks for exact match. `reference.csv` is static and `csv.csv` is dynamic and `category` filed in `csv1` is dynamic with possible matches. So I am using `find.all' to find all occurrence of matching patterns

Comment: @Abhi_J I updated the question. I have explored merge however it looks for exact match. reference.csv is static and csv.csv is dynamic and category filed in csv1 is dynamic with possible matches. So I am using `find.all' to find all occurrence of matching patterns

Comment: Exactly this is necessary add to question ;)

Comment: @jezrael - I Agree will do it here after :-)

Comment: Btw, I think you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56315491/2901002)

Comment: @Abhi_J I tried below  `df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv') df2 = pd.read_csv('reference.csv')   my_dict = dict(zip(df2['Category'].values, df2['Complexity'].values)) print(my_dict) newdf = df1['Complexity'] = df1['Category'].apply(lambda x: my_dict [x]) ` I see error as `KeyError: 'Disk Space Utilization'` which is one of the category item in CSV1

Comment: @goe I've updated my answer with a new method to match the key. Also does jezrael's suggestion help?

Comment: @Abhi_J Thank you, I tried as per your suggestion but this time no error however complexity is not getting updated.

Comment: Updated? isn't Complexity a new column to be added to csv1, is it not added?

Comment: @Abhi_J yes correct its not added.

Comment: Which Dataframe are you printing/checking? btw `newdf = df1['Complexity'] = df1['Category'].apply(lambda x: my_dict [x])` this code will create a `pandas-series` called newdf not a dataframe.

Comment: @Abhi_J `import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('reference.csv')
my_dict = dict(zip(df2['Category'].values, df2['Complexity'].values))
def match_key(key, default_value):
    for d_key in my_dict.keys():
        if key in d_key or d_key in key:
            return my_dict[d_key]

    return default_value
df1['Complexity'] = df1['Category'].apply(lambda x: match_key(x, 'default_value'))
print(df1)'  I used this and `df1` is printing as expected. But its how can I write to CSV i.e i.e `df1` or `csv1.csv`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230365/discussion-between-abhi-j-and-goe).

Comment: @Abhi_J - I am requesting you help again, current code we are looking for the string match, for example `CPU Utilization` from reference file and look in the Category of actual column, this will work if it is `CPU Utilization of windows` However if the category filed in actual csv  is `Utilization of CPU` then it might..what I can do to do all possible combinations something like `find.all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach:

```py
my_dict = dict(zip(reference_df['Category'].values, reference_df['Complexity'].values))

def match_key(key, default_value):
    for d_key in my_dict.keys():
        if key in d_key or d_key in key:
            return my_dict[d_key]

    return default_value

CSV1_df['Complexity'] = CSV1_df['Category'].apply(lambda x: match_key(x, 'default'))
```

**Explanation:**

1. Build a `dict` by zipping *Category* and *Complexity* columns in reference `Dataframe`, i.e. `{'Server Down': 'Simple', 'Network Interface down': 'Complex'...}`
2. Use `apply` and a `lambda` function to get corresponding *Complexity* values from the dictionary using each *Category* value in CSV1 `Dataframe` as key
3. We define a function to find if *Category* value in CSV1 `Dataframe` is a substring of any key in the dictionary or wise-versa and use it in `apply`
4. Save it to new column in *CSV1* `Dataframe`