# Check string values in one column df to another column df with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
import pandas as pd

first_df = pd.DataFrame({'Full Name': ['Mulligan Nick & Mary', 'Tsang S C', 'Hattie J A C '],
                         'Address': ['270 Claude Road', '13 Sunnyridge Place', '18A Empire Road']})

second_df = pd.DataFrame({'Owner' : ['David James Mulligan', 'Brenda Joy Mulligan ', 'Helen Kwok Hattie'],
                          'Add Match': ['19 Dexter Avenue', 'Claude Road ', 'Building NO 512']})
```

Is there anyway to match only the first string in `Full Name` column to the last string in `Owner` column.

If there is a match, I then want to compare `Address` against `Add match` to see if there are any like values. If the first condition passes but the second condition fails, this would not be added into the new data frame.

Using a left join results in:

```
new_df = first_df.merge(second_df, how='left', left_on = ['Full Name', 'Address'], right_on = ['Owner', 'Add Match'])
print(new_df.head())

              Full Name              Address Owner Add Match
0  Mulligan Nick & Mary      270 Claude Road   NaN       NaN
1             Tsang S C  13 Sunnyridge Place   NaN       NaN
2         Hattie J A C       18A Empire Road   NaN       NaN
```

However the output wanted would look more like this:

```
new_df

Name                 Address
----                 --------
Brenda Joy Mulligan  Claude Road
```

Comment: Could you add to your question what you have tried so far? Why a simple inner join such as `first_df.merge(second_df, how='inner', left_on = ['Full Name', 'Address'], right_on = ['Owner', 'Add Match'])` wouldn't work?

Comment: Using an inner join, `new_df = first_df.merge(second_df, how='inner', left_on = ['Full Name', 'Address'], right_on = ['Owner', 'Add Match'])`gives me an empty data frame with 20 columns.

Comment: If an `inner` join is returning empty results it is because it can't match both keys on the initial dataframes. Change the `how` key to `left` or `right` to see if it is closer to what you are looking for. However, from your examples it is not quite clear what is your problem, try following this guide on [how to write good pandas questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Also, do not forget to add to your question what is the solution that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13680953/2464671) you could employ a similar solution.

### TL;DR

```
first_df[['last_name', 'start_name']] = first_df['Full Name'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
second_df['last_name'] = second_df['Owner'].str.split(' ').str[-1]
df_final = first_df.merge(second_df, how='inner', left_on=['last_name'], right_on=['last_name'])
address_matches = df_final.apply(lambda x: True if difflib.get_close_matches(x['Address'], [x['Add Match']], n=1, cutoff=0.8) else False, axis=1)
df_final = df_final[address_matches].drop(columns=['last_name', 'start_name', 'Full Name', 'Address']).rename(columns={'Owner':'Name', 'Add Match': 'Address'})
```

### Step-by-step

Initially, you extract the last name keys you want.

```
first_df[['last_name', 'start_name']] = first_df['Full Name'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
second_df['last_name'] = second_df['Owner'].str.split(' ').str[-1]
```

**PS:** Here we are using built-in string methods from pandas/numpy combo given your instructions. But if it fits you better you could also apply the similarity methods (e.g., `difflib.get_close_matches`) shown down below for the address part.

Next, you perform an inner join of these dataframes to match the `last_name`  key.

```
df_temp = first_df.merge(second_df, how='inner', left_on=['last_name'], right_on=['last_name'])
```

Then you apply the `difflib.get_close_matches` with the desired similarity (I used `cutoff=0.8` because above this value there were no values returned) method to mark which rows contain matches and subsequently get only the rows you want.

```
matches_mask = df_final.apply(lambda x: True if difflib.get_close_matches(x['Address'], [x['Add Match']], n=1, cutoff=0.8) else False, axis=1)
df_final = df_final[matches_mask].drop(columns=['last_name', 'start_name'])
```

```
Full Name               Address             Owner                   Add Match

Mulligan Nick & Mary    270 Claude Road     Brenda Joy Mulligan     Claude Road
```

Finally, to get match the format of the results posted at the end of your question you drop or rename some columns.

```
df_final.drop(columns=['Full Name', 'Address']).rename(columns={'Owner':'Name', 'Add Match': 'Address'})
```

```
Owner                   Add Match

Brenda Joy Mulligan     Claude Road
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of the `difflib` module from Python standard library to find similarities between different columns.
For instance, you can define the following function:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def compare_df(left, right, col: str):
    left[f"{col}_match_ratio"] = 0

    for value in left[col]:
        best_ratio = 0
        for other in right[col]:
            result = SequenceMatcher(None, str(value), str(other)).ratio()
            if result > best_ratio:
                best_ratio = result
        left.loc[left[col] == value, f"{col}_match_ratio"] = round(best_ratio, 2)
```

Then:

- you just have to make sure that the column you want to compare on have the same name in both dfs
- you call df_compare(first_df, second_df, "Owner") which will add "Owner_match_ratio" column to second_df
- finally, you filter second df on the desired minimum match ratio (70 % for instance) like this: `new_df = second_df.loc[second_df["Owner_match_ratio"] > 0.7, :]`