# Join Pandas DataFrames matching by string and substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

i want to merge two dataframes by partial string match.
I have two data frames to combine. First df1 consists of 130.000 rows like this:

```
id    text                        xc1       xc2
1     adidas men shoes            52465     220
2     vakko men suits             49220     224
3     burberry men shirt          78248     289
4     prada women shoes           45780     789
5     lcwaikiki men sunglasses    34788     745
```

and second df2 consists of 8000 rows like this:

```
id    keyword               abc1     abc2
1     men shoes             1000     11
2     men suits             2000     12
3     men shirt             3000     13
4     women socks           4000     14
5     men sunglasses        5000     15
```

After matching between **keyword** and **text**, outputshould look like this:

```
id    text                        xc1       xc2   keyword         abc1  abc2
1     adidas men shoes            52465     220   men shoes       1000  11
2     vakko men suits             49220     224   men suits       2000  12
3     burberry men shirt          78248     289   men shirt       3000  13
4     lcwaikiki men sunglasses    34788     745   men sunglasses  5000  15
```

Comment: Is it possible the partial string match is at the middle of text in `df1` ? e.g.  `vakko men suits blue` ?

Comment: @SeaBean Yes. There are such examples when I examine the dataset.

Comment: Are the id are in same order?

Comment: @AnuragDabas unfortunately no. the row numbers of both data frames are different

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908516/14066512

Comment: One more complication would be `men suits` in `df2` should not match `abc women suits` in `df1`, right ?

Comment: @SeaBean yes I wouldn't want it to match like that.

Comment: In such case, you cannot use most of the similar answers in StackOverflows that use simple substring test like `stringA in stringB`.  Such kind of test will fail with false match of `men suits` in `keyword` with `women suits` in `text` since it returns `True` for test of `'men suits' in 'women suits'`    We have to make use of regex with the consideration of word boundary to avoid the false match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's approach by cross join the 2 dataframes and then filter by matching string with substring, as follows:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')    # for Pandas version >= 1.2.0 (released in Dec 2020)

import re
mask = df3.apply(lambda x: (re.search(rf"\b{x['keyword']}\b", str(x['text']))) != None, axis=1)
df_out = df3.loc[mask]
```

If your Pandas version is older than 1.2.0 (released in Dec 2020) and does not support merge with `how='cross'`, you can replace the merge statement with:

```
# For Pandas version < 1.2.0
df3 = df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
```

After the cross join, we created a boolean mask to filter for the cases that `keyword` is found within `text` by using `re.search` within `.apply()`.

We have to use `re.search` instead of simple Python substring test like `stringA in stringB` found in most of the similar answers in StackOverflow. Such kind of test will fail with false match of `'men suits'` in `keyword` with `'women suits'` in `text` since it returns `True` for test of `'men suits' in 'women suits'`.

We use regex with a pair of word boundary `\b` meta-characters around the `keyword` (regex pattern: `rf"\b{x['keyword']}\b"`) to ensure matching only for whole word match for `text` in `df1`, i.e. `men suits` in `df2` would not match with `women suits` in `df1` since the word `women` does not have a word boundary between the letters `wo` and `men`.

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)


    id_x                      text    xc1  xc2  id_y         keyword  abc1  abc2
0      1          adidas men shoes  52465  220     1       men shoes  1000    11
6      2           vakko men suits  49220  224     2       men suits  2000    12
12     3        burberry men shirt  78248  289     3       men shirt  3000    13
24     5  lcwaikiki men sunglasses  34788  745     5  men sunglasses  5000    15
```

Here, columns `id_x` and `id_y` are the original `id` column in `df1` and `df2` respectively.  As seen from the comment, these are just row numbers of the dataframes that you may not care about.  We can then remove these 2 columns and reset index to clean up the layout:

```
df_out = df_out.drop(['id_x', 'id_y'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Final outcome**

```
print(df_out)


                       text    xc1  xc2         keyword  abc1  abc2
0          adidas men shoes  52465  220       men shoes  1000    11
1           vakko men suits  49220  224       men suits  2000    12
2        burberry men shirt  78248  289       men shirt  3000    13
3  lcwaikiki men sunglasses  34788  745  men sunglasses  5000    15
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I get an error like this: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`  could some of the values ​​be because it is integer?

Comment: @muratmert41  In such case, cast `x['text']` to string first, using `str(x['text'])`.  You can refer to my edited codes above.

Comment: @muratmert41  Feel free to let me know if any further thing I can help!  :-)

Comment: your answers really help me a lot. I'm not getting an error anymore. but there are some minor problems that prevent me from getting the right result. I'm working on them.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot that. thank you again.

Comment: @muratmert41 Welcome!  Good luck to solving your minor problems soon!

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by ordering the keywords longest-first, so that "women suits" matches "before "men suits"

```
lkeys = df2.keyword.reindex(df2.keyword.str.len().sort_values(ascending=False).index)
```

Now define a matching function; each `text` value from `df1` will be passed as `s` to find a matching keyword:

```
def is_match(arr, s):
    for a in arr:
        if a in s:
            return a
    return None
```

Now we can extract the keyword from each `text` in df1, and add it to a new column:

```
df1['keyword'] = df1['text'].apply(lambda x: is_match(lkeys, x))
```

We now have everything we need for a standard merge:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='keyword')
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.  I guess some values ​​contain int values. for example for example: "16 inch Bicycle Rim".  therefore I get an error like this: `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`