# Python fuzzy string search in Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, findall, fuzzy

I have 500 TIFFs that I am using pytesseract to extract all text from.  I'm then searching for a 'list' (search_list) of word in the returned string (df['String'] ) from pytesseract (in a pandas dataframe)

This works great using the formula below,

`df['Found'] = df3['String'].str.findall('(' + '|'.join(search_list) + ')')`

I want to incorporate fuzzy searching (regex?) so it will also look for substitutions ie. 'g' instead of 'c' etc where the OCR was not great.  I found the singlwe line of code below, but cannot seem to integrate this into the above successfully.  How would I go about this?

`regex.findall("(ATAGGAGAAGATGATGTATA){s<=2}", "ATAGAGCAAGATGATGTATA", overlapped=True)`

**Edit:** Note 'String' is over 500 characters, whereas the items in 'search_list' are only 10-15 characters long.  This works fine with my originla code, it just cannot cope with any substitutions.

**Edit2 : Example:**

String = 'eh house tree unicorn jantern s g w there was 123 treadmill fountain 1 5 funny grash cymbal shampoo'

search =['crash cymbal','unicorn lantern']

I would like both 'crash cymbal' and 'unicorn lantern' to be found using fuzzy logic due to 1 substitution.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56315491/9081267) answer.

Comment: Do you just want to use the current `regex.findall("(ATAGGAGAAGATGATGTATA){s<=2}", "ATAGAGCAAGATGATGTATA", overlapped=True)` in Pandas? Or do you ask if you can allow only specific substitutions (only `g` or `c` can be substituted?) Can you please provide a test string and expected output?

Comment: I want to use the fuzzy functionality, but using 'search_list' and 'string' as per my original code.  I should point out, 'string' is upto 500 characters long, and each item in 'search_list' is only 10-15 characters.  therefore I do not beleive it can just be a join/merge, it has to be a findall (where it's looking within a longer string)

Comment: Ok, is `df["Found"] = df3["String"].apply(lambda r: regex.findall("(ATAGGAGAAGATGATGTATA){s<=2}", r, overlapped=True))` all you want? I don't get why you have `df` and `df3`, but let's assume they have the same amount of rows.

Comment: Mark, please provide feedback on what your intention is.

Comment: Apologies, it seems I'm not very clear.  the ATAGGAGAAA.... is just an example snippet of code I found using fuzzy search logic.   I need to search df3['String'] for strings contained in a list called 'search_list'.  However df3['string'] is upto 500 characters, and any members of 'search_list' (only 10-15 characters long) may be contained within it with soem possible substitutions i.e. i to j c to g etc.  I have successfully managed the search, returning all exact matches using my originla code.  I'm struggling on how to incorporate looking for substitutions at character level in search_list

Comment: So, `df["Found"] = df3["String"].apply(lambda r: regex.findall('(?:' + '|'.join(search_list) + '){s<=2:[A-Z]}', r, overlapped=True))`? Extract those strings with up to 2 substitutions among uppercase letters?

Comment: Can I please ask what the ', r,' is doing before overlapped=True, and also the additional characters in '(:?' after findall - I only have ( in my original code ?

Comment: Not `:?` but `?:`, the order is very important, but in this case, if used with `re.findall`, it is not relevant, actually. Shall I post as an answer? Does it work for you?

Comment: Did that work as expected?

Comment: No, it does not quite yet, as I am getting hundreds of '','','','' etc matches mixed in with the substituted finds.  I thought I may have a blank item (or single/double character length item) in my search list, but I do not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you can use

```py
import regex
#...
rx = fr'(?:{"|".join(search_list)}){{s<=2:[A-Z]}}'
df["Found"] = df3["String"].apply(lambda r: regex.findall(rx, r, overlapped=True))
```

The pattern will look like `(?:a|b|c|etc){s<=2:[A-Z]}` and will match either `a` or `b` or `c` even if up to two uppercase letters are substituted for some other letters.