# Pandas merge dataframe by partial and full match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
State    City               Population  Year
ALABAMA  Alexander City     14947       2020
ALABAMA  Owens Cross Roads  9972        2020
ARIZONA  Miami              1863        2020
....
```

and another dataframe like so:

```
State    City               val         Year
ALABAMA  Alexander city     55.60       2020
ALABAMA  Owens Crossroads   22.09       2020
ARIZONA  Miami              45.23       2020
....
```

Now, I would like to merge these dataframes by full match of `State` & `Year`, & partial match of `City` as the city names are not standardized. Any similarity algorithm will do (soundex, Levenshtein, difflib's).

And finally get something like this:

```
State    City               val         Year    Population  
ALABAMA  Alexander city     55.60       2020    14947
ALABAMA  Owens Crossroads   22.09       2020    9972
ARIZONA  Miami              45.23       2020    1863
....
```

> EDIT:

This is not the same as some other ques on SO (like: [is it possible to do fuzzy match merge with python pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas)) as I want to merge on multiple columns, some exact match and one best partial match.

Comment: You'll need to decide what the rules are for a "partial match"...

Comment: @JonClements edited my question to reflect that

Comment: So... create a new column with your "partial key"... join on the full stuff... what doesn't match - join on the partial key... ? What's the difficultly you're having exactly?