# Optimized way of matching information from 2 dataframes based on strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have information on two distinct dataframes and I can only match them by their name. The problem is the names are different for both dataframes. So currently my plan is to match them by using `in` due to most of them only differ by one word:

Example:

Dataframe 1:
'Viazem XL 360mg'

Dataframe 2:
'Viazem XL 360mg capsules'

```
i = 0 
for i in range (df1.shape[0]):
    j = 0
    for j in range (df1.shape[0]):
        if (df2['name'][j] in df2['name'][i]):
            df1['Documents'].iloc[i] = df2['Documents'].iloc[j]
            break
```

I'm using a for cycle but that takes a lot of time, what can be a faster approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13680953/2538939