# Python Match 2 data frames by name where one is full name and other first name initial and last name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to merge 2 dataframes by name where one column is name + last name and the other only first name initial + last name.

Example:

df1:

```
    name
John Doe
```

df2:

```
  name
J. Doe
```

Comment: you can use `fuzzywuzzy` and use his fucntion : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56315491/18938956

Comment: can you provide the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to change the format of `df1['name']` and feed this to `merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2,
          left_on=df1['name'].str.replace(r'^(.)\w+', r'\1.', regex=True),
          right_on='name'
         )
```

*NB. check the documentation of [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for more parameters to format the output, in particular `suffixes` to customize the column names.*

output:

```
     name    name_x  name_y
0  J. Doe  John Doe  J. Doe
```

example input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John Doe']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['J. Doe']})
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I was trying to do this for the last couple of days. The expected output was J. Doe.