# How do I merge two dataframes by partial string match?

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, substring

I have two dataframes of Premier League soccer players:

df1:

```
ID      Player              Team             Pos
1       Gabriel Dos Santos  Arsenal          DF
218     Conor Gallagher     Crystal Palace   MF
396     Gabriel Jesus       Manchester City  FW
```

df2:

```
ID  name                            team     minutes
15  Gabriel dos Santos Magalhães    Arsenal  3063
18  Gabriel Martinelli Silva        Arsenal  1855
27  Gabriel Fernando de Jesus       Arsenal  1871
```

I want to merge the dataframes by name/player and keep ALL rows and columns of d1 and d2 even if a name is not in both dataframes. It would look something like this:

```
ID  name                            team     minutes  ID   Pos  Team
15  Gabriel dos Santos Magalhães    Arsenal  3063     1    DF   Arsenal
18  Gabriel Martinelli Silva        Arsenal  1855     NA   NA   NA
27  Gabriel Fernando de Jesus       Arsenal  1871     396  FW   Manchester City
NA  Conor Gallagher                 NA       NA       218  MF   Crystal Palace
```

The only problem is that the names in d1 do not exactly match the names in d2 (think of d1 as a partial name, or substring of d2 names), and some of the names in d1 are not in d2 (and viceversa).

I did this:

```
d2[d2['name'].apply(lambda player: d1['Player'].str.contains(player)).any(1)]
```

But it's not working. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package `fuzzywuzzy` to do fuzzy matching.

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Strawberry']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['Aple', 'Mango', 'Orag', 'Straw', 'Bannanna', 'Berry']})

def fuzzy_merge(df_1, df_2, key1, key2, threshold=90, limit=2):
    """
    :param df_1: the left table to join
    :param df_2: the right table to join
    :param key1: key column of the left table
    :param key2: key column of the right table
    :param threshold: how close the matches should be to return a match, based on Levenshtein distance
    :param limit: the amount of matches that will get returned, these are sorted high to low
    :return: dataframe with boths keys and matches
    """
    s = df_2[key2].tolist()
    
    m = df_1[key1].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, s, limit=limit))    
    df_1['matches'] = m
    
    m2 = df_1['matches'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([i[0] for i in x if i[1] >= threshold]))
    df_1['matches'] = m2
    
    return df_1

fuzzy_merge(df1, df2, 'Key', 'Key', threshold=80)
```

Result:

```
          Key       matches
0       Apple          Aple
1      Banana      Bannanna
2      Orange          Orag
3  Strawberry  Straw, Berry
```

See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas) for more information.