# Fuzzy match across a dataframe and find the scores for all the columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, fuzzy-comparison

I have a dataframe - df1

| Marketing | Sales | IT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| marketing manager | sales lead | software eng |
| marketing spec | sales mgr | data scientist |

And another dataframe - df2 -

| Profession | Job Title |
| --- | --- |
| IT | data science manager |
| Marketing | Marketing manager |

I need to fuzzy match all the job titles from dataframe 2 (df2) to all the rows and columns in df1 and find fuzzy score of each element .

Sample output - Only for datascience manager (need to create such tables for all the Job Titles in dataframe 1 and find the column which has maximum scores above 90 so as to classify the job title in a profession:

| Marketing | Sales | IT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 0 | 30 |
| 0 | 0 | 91 |

Comment: you must provide a reproducible input

Comment: @mozway added the dataframes as a table, please let me know if this helps

Comment: It is better, now you should check for similar questions, try the solutions and add here the exact code you tried and how it failed if really you don't manage. This problem has already been solved many times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dataframes by partial string match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72974891/how-do-i-merge-two-dataframes-by-partial-string-match)