# Columns must be same length as key Error python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I have 2 CSV files in file1 I have list of research groups names. in file2 I have list of the Research full name with location as wall. I want to join these 2 csv file if the have the words matches in them.

Pandas ValueError: "Columns must be same length as key" I am using Jupyter Labs for this.

"df1[["f2_research_groups_names", "f2_location"]] = df1.apply(fn, axis=1)"

cvs row size for file1.csv 5000 data, and for file2.csv I have about 15,000

file1.csv

| research_groups_names_f1 |
| --- |
| Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS) |
| CAS |
| U-M |
| UQ |
| University of California, Los Angeles |
| Harvard University |

file2.csv

| research_groups_names_f2 | Locatio_f2 |
| --- | --- |
| Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS) | China |
| University of Michigan (U-M) | USA |
| The University of Queensland (UQ) | USA |
| University of California | USA |

file_output.csv

| research_groups_names_f1 | research_groups_names_f2 | Locatio_f2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chinese Academy of Sciences | Chinese Academy of Sciences(CAS) | China |
| CAS | Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS) | China |
| U-M | University of Michigan (U-M) | USA |
| UQ | The University of Queensland (UQ) | Australia |
| Harvard University | Not found | USA |
| University of California, Los Angeles | University of California | USA |

```
import pandas as pd
    df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
    
    df2 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')

    df1 = df1.add_prefix('f1_')
    df2 = df2.add_prefix('f2_')

def fn(row):
    for _, n in df2.iterrows():
        if (
            n["research_groups_names_f1"] == row["research_groups_names_f2"]
            or row["research_groups_names_f1"] in n["research_groups_names_f2"]
        ):
            return n


df1[["f2_research_groups_names", "f2_location"]] = df1.apply(fn, axis=1)
df1 = df1.rename(columns={"research_groups_names": "f1_research_groups_names"})
print(df1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it possible to do fuzzy match merge with python pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas)

Comment: No I tried it and it didn't work for me

Comment: can you help me slove this

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're trying to merge on some very different values.  Fuzzy matching may not help because the distance between CAS and Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS) is quite large.  The two have very little in common.  You'll have to develop some custom approach based on your understanding of what the possible group names could be.  Here is on approach that gets you most of the way there.

The idea here is to match on the university name OR the abbreviation.  So in df2 we can split off the abbreviation and explode into a new row, remove the parenthesis, and in df remove any abbreviation surrounded by parentehsis.

The only leftover value is UCLA, which is the only sample that doesn't follow the same structure as the others.  In this case fuzzy matching like I mentioned in my first comment probably would help.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'research_groups_names_f1':[
'Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS)',
'CAS',
'U-M',
'UQ',
'University of California, Los Angeles',
'Harvard University']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'research_groups_names_f2': ['Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS)',
  'University of Michigan (U-M)',
  'The University of Queensland (UQ)',
  'University of California'],
 'Locatio_f2': ['China', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA']})



df2['key'] = df2['research_groups_names_f2'].str.split('\(')
df2 = df2.explode('key')
df2['key'] = df2['key'].str.replace('\(|\)','', regex=True)

df['key'] = df['research_groups_names_f1'].str.replace('\(.*\)','',regex=True)

df.merge(df2, on='key', how='left').drop(columns='key')
```

Output

```
               research_groups_names_f1           research_groups_names_f2 Locatio_f2
0      Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS)  Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS)      China
1                                    CAS  Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS)      China
2                                    U-M       University of Michigan (U-M)        USA
3                                     UQ  The University of Queensland (UQ)        USA
4  University of California, Los Angeles                                NaN        NaN
5                     Harvard University                                NaN        NaN
```

Comment: can change the df= pd.dataframe to pd.read_csv?