# Get values from another dataframe if NaN after merge by incomplete name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataFrames that after merge by "Name" some rows retun NaN because the "Names" are incomplete.

df1

| Name | Info 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Walter | Adress 1 |
| john wick | Adress 1 |

df2

| Name | Info 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Walter White | Male |
| john wick | Male |

```
df2 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Name', how='left')
```

I'm geting

| Name | Info 1 | Info 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Walter | NaN | NaN |
| john wick | Adress 1 | Male |

I Want

| Name | Info 1 | Info 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Walter White | Adress 1 | Male |
| john wick | Adress 1 | Male |

How can I treat rows, to try get values by substring, if return NaN? I dont know if use merge in first time was the best logic.

Comment: check this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas

Comment: the fuzzywuzzy from the link above will help you better

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df2 = pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,on='Name', how='left')
```

this depends on the resemblance of the different values

Comment: I thought .merge_asof works with Int's and datatime and not with strings?

Comment: It will work on string as well, of course not as good as for integers and datetime because it will be comparing the start of the string

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working is because pandas doesn't consider "Walter" and "Walter White" as same values.
Thus when you perform a left join on df1 it keeps all the values of df1 and adds the values from df2 that have the same "Name" column values. Since *walter* is not present in df2 it adds NaN in info2 column(again "walter" and "walter white" are different).
One way you could solve this is by creating two separate columns for "First_Name" and "Last_Name" and then try merging on "First_Name"
something like

```
df1["First_Name"] = df1.apply(lambda row: row['Name'].split()[0], axis = 1)
df2["First_Name"] = df2.apply(lambda row: row['Name'].split()[0], axis = 1)
```

Then simply use the same merge as you did...
`df2 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='First_Name', how='left')`