# Matching strings in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have two dataframes named *codes* and *phrases*

codes :

| code | keywords |
| --- | --- |
| bg | burger |
| bg | burgers |
| cbg | chicken burger |
| cbg | burger chicken |
| cbg | chicken burgers |
| -- | -- |
| -- | -- |

phrases :

| text |
| --- |
| burgers near me |
| chicken burgers around NYC |
| -- |
| -- |

Using python I want to build a dataframe like this :

| text | code |
| --- | --- |
| burgers near me | bg |
| chicken burgers around NYC | cbg |
| -- | -- |
| -- | -- |

I am trying to identify which *keywords* from *codes* best match with each record of *phrases*.

If I simply use string contains function, burgers would match with both the phrases above.
Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56315491/3275464) help?

Comment: You could sort "codes" by length of keywords and process it in this order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a column to `codes` with the length of each keyword.  Then start assigning the largest number of characters first. With each iteration, calculate a new index to find the remaining blanks and the matches so that only those are filled.

```
phrases['code'] = ''
codes['Length'] = codes.keywords.str.len()
codes = codes.sort_values('Length', ascending=False)

for _, row in codes.iterrows()
    ix_blank = phrases.code.eq('')
    ix_match = phrases.text.str.contains(f'\\b{row.keywords}\\b')
    phrases.loc[ix_blank & ix_match, 'code'] = row.code
```